# Drawing Rotated views while ignoring the Bounding box

Tags: graphics

I am trying to make an animation of a rotating cube using the following code:

```
cube = GraphicsComplex[
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}},
Polygon[{{1, 2, 4, 3}, {5, 6, 8, 7}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {3, 4, 8, 7}, {1, 3, 7, 5}, {2, 4, 8, 6}}]
]

cubes = Table[
Graphics3D[{Rotate[cube, x, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}]}, 
ViewPoint -> {3, 1/2, -2}, ViewVertical -> {1, 1, 1}, 
Boxed -> False], {x, 0, 2 Pi/3 - Pi/48, Pi/24}]
```

However, as the cube rotates, the bounding box (which is not drawn because `Boxed->False`) causes the image of the cube to be shrunk to fit the larger bounding box in the field of view. Is there a way to keep the scale constant and not vary with the varying size of the bounding box?

I've gone through the list of options for `Graphics3D`, yet none seem to help.

---

**Edit:**

Heike's answer works like a charm!  For those interested, here is the finished code, used to create the illustration for [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115743/question-about-a-rotating-cube/115797#115797) on math.SE.

```
cube =
GraphicsComplex[
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}},
Polygon[{{1, 2, 4, 3}, {5, 6, 8, 7}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {3, 4, 8, 7}, {1, 3, 7, 5}, {2, 4, 8, 6}}]
];

envelope[t_] := If[t < 1, t, If[t < 2, Sqrt[(2 t - 3)^2 + 3]/2, 3 - t]]

lozenge = 
Rotate[
RevolutionPlot3D[{Sqrt[2/3] envelope[t], t/Sqrt[3]}, {t, 0, 3}, MaxRecursion -> 5][[1]],
{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}];

enveloped = 
Table[
Graphics3D[{Rotate[cube, x, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}],  Opacity[1/2], lozenge},
ViewVector -> {3, 1/2, -2}, ViewAngle -> 30 Degree, ViewCenter -> {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, 
ViewVertical -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 300],
{x, 0, 2 Pi/3 - Pi/48, Pi/24}];

Export["enveloped.gif", enveloped, "GraphicsList", "DisplayDurations" -> {.05}]
```

---

**Migration to Newer Versions**

With changes to Mathematica, the code above does not parse. When I fixed the code so it parsed, it renders on screen nicely, but upon `Export`, it rendered pretty badly (at least on the Mac Powerbook, which has 144 dpi screen resolution and tells some applications  to render at 144 and others to render at 72 dpi). I was able to adjust some parameters in the code and in the `Export` statement to get an almost identical output.

```
cube =
GraphicsComplex[
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}},
Polygon[{{1, 2, 4, 3}, {5, 6, 8, 7}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {3, 4, 8, 7}, {1, 3, 7, 5}, {2, 4, 8, 6}}]
];

envelope[t_] := If[t < 1, t, If[t < 2, Sqrt[(2 t - 3)^2 + 3]/2, 3 - t]]

lozenge = 
Rotate[
RevolutionPlot3D[{Sqrt[2/3] envelope[t], t/Sqrt[3]}, {t, 0, 3}, MaxRecursion -> 5,
PlotTheme -> "Classic",Exclusions -> None, MeshStyle -> {Thickness[1/144]}][[1]],
{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}];

enveloped = 
Table[
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Thickness[1/144]], 
Rotate[cube, x, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}], Opacity[1/2], lozenge}, ViewVector -> {3, 1/2, -2},
ViewAngle -> 30 Degree, ViewCenter -> {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, ViewVertical -> {1, 1, 1},
Background -> None, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 300, Lighting -> "Classic"],
{x, 0, 2 Pi/3 - Pi/48, Pi/24}]

Export["enveloped.gif", enveloped, "GraphicsList", "DisplayDurations" -> .05,
"AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity, ImageSize -> 300, ImageResolution -> 144]

(* For the high resolution image, we need to change the Thickness Directive to *)
(* Thickness[1/288] then *)

Export["enveloped2.gif", enveloped, "GraphicsList", "DisplayDurations" -> .05,
"AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity, ImageSize -> 600, ImageResolution -> 144]
```

Comment: Try `SphericalRegion->True`?

Comment: @Yves: Thanks. I did, but it produced the same varying size. I also tried ViewRange, but it only clips in distance from the ViewPoint, so anything affecting the width and height are not clipped.

Comment: Nice! By always displaying `lozenge` you should even get away with using `ViewPoint`, because the bounding box of the object is constant.

Comment: @Yves: That is true. Luckily, I didn't add `lozenge` until later, so that I could learn what the nomenclature of `Graphics3D` really means.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The variation in size is due to variation in camera position and viewing angle. Since `ViewPoint` uses special coordinates which depend on the bounding box it's better to use `ViewVector` instead (or even `ViewMatrix` if you can make it work). To keep the viewing angle fixed you should give an explicit value for `ViewAngle`. To place the object at the right position in the field of view you could use `ViewCentre`. For the example above you could do something like

```
cubes = Table[
  Graphics3D[{Rotate[cube, x, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}]}, 
   ViewVector -> {3, 1/2, -2}, 
   ViewAngle -> 35 Degree,
   ViewCenter -> {.5, .5, .5},
   ViewVertical -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> False],
  {x, 0, 2 Pi/3 - Pi/48, Pi/24}]
```

Comment: Ah, I shouldn't assume that `ViewPoint` is the point at which the viewer sits. I wrote a Camera Library for QuickDraw GX (when I worked at Apple), and I was assuming Mathematica's terminology was similar. I should read the documentation for `ViewPoint`, which says just what you said. I see that `ViewVector` and `ViewCenter` are the options I should have been setting. Thank you very much!