# Autorotating 3D plots

Tags: graphics, export, graphics3d, animation

These days, I have to produce quite a few 3D surface plots (mostly functions of the type $\rho(\theta,\phi)$ plotted with `SphericalPlot3D`). To exchange these results colleagues who don’t use Mathematica, or to include them in presentations, I need to export these plots as movies showing the surface rotating. What I’d love to do is to be able to choose one graph, and just export it as autorotating around the current vertical axis (i.e. the axis contain in the plane of the screen, and directed upwards).

This not being possible, I'm trying to do the next best thing: a procedure that takes as an argument the produced 3D graphics (say, the output of `SphericalPlot3D`) and makes it automatically rotate. Here’s what I’ve been able to do with `Animate`, but I could follow the same logic and export it directly instead.

```
rotateMeHarder[g_] := Module[{range},
   range = Max /@ (Abs@PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange]);
   Animate[
    Show[
     Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, Line[{{-1.2*range[[1]], 0, 0}, {1.2*range[[1]], 0, 0}}]}],
     Graphics3D[{Green, Thick, Line[{{0, -1.2*range[[2]], 0}, {0, 1.2*range[[2]], 0}}]}],
     Graphics3D[{Blue, Thick, Line[{{0, 0, -1.2*range[[3]]}, {0, 0, 1.2*range[[3]]}}]}],
     g,
     ViewPoint -> RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}][{0, 2*Max@range, 0.2*Max@range}],
     SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False],
    {θ, π/20, 2 π + π/20, π/20}]
   ];

p = SphericalPlot3D[
  10 + 5*Re@SphericalHarmonicY[3, -3, θ, ϕ], θ, ϕ,
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7]];
rotateMeHarder[p]
```

---

What I like about this:

- It does generate a nicely rotating object in simple cases.
- It draws axis lines on top of my graph, but that's just because it looks great on my pictures, it's not a requirement for the question…

What I don’t like, or am unsure about:

- It doesn’t start with the current orientation of the graph, but works with a fixed rotation vector (along the 3D $z$ axis) and a fixed starting position (slightly above the $xy$ plane). If I understood [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3528/700) correctly, they is not way of retrieving the current viewpoint for a given interactive 3D graph. So bad!.
- It doesn’t seem very robust. In particular, it only works for 3D plots centered around the origin, which extend about the same length in each axis direction (i.e. does not deal with very anisotropic surfaces).
- It leaves a lot of white padding around the graphics.

---

So, the question is: what do you think of this code? **How could I make it more general, more robust, or in any way closer to my initial goal of a one-size-fits-all exporting procedure for 3D graphics?**

Comment: Adding RotationAction -> "Fit" will keep objects inside your frame during Animation.

Comment: Related question: [Drawing Rotated views while ignoring the Bounding box](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2565/12)

Comment: The old ``Graphics`Animation` `` package had the `SpinShow[]` function...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Note that `ViewPoint` is given in specially scaled coordinates which depend on amongst things the size of the bounding box. To get better control over the positioning of the camera you could use `ViewVector` instead, which is given in terms of the coordinates of the plot. You could for example do something like this:

```
rotateMeHarder1[g_, vertical_, viewpoint0_, center_List: {0, 0, 0}, 
  nframes_Integer: 15, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{grlist},
  grlist = 
   Table[Show[g, ViewVertical -> vertical, 
     ViewVector -> {RotationMatrix[2 Pi/nframes i, 
          vertical].(viewpoint0 - center) + center, center},
     SphericalRegion -> True, opts], {i, 0, nframes - 1}]]
```

where `g` is the `Graphics3D` object, `vertical` is the vertical axis, `viewpoint0` is the starting position of the camera, `center` is the center of the graph, `nframes` is the number of frames, and `opts` are additional options of the graph.

**Usage**

To create an animation of the plot `p` in the original question rotating around the axis anchored at `{10, 0, 0}` and direction `{0, 1, 0}`, and initial camera position `{30, 30, 30}` you could do something like

```
p = SphericalPlot3D[10 + 5*Re@ SphericalHarmonicY[3, -3, θ, ϕ], 
  θ, ϕ, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Green}, {Thick, Blue}}, 
  Ticks -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7]];

grlist = rotateMeHarder1[p, {0, 1, 0}, {30, 30, 30}, {10, 0, 0}, 20, 
  ViewAngle -> 50 Degree]

ListAnimate[grlist]
```

Note that I'm using `ViewAngle` to adjust the size of the graphics relative to the viewing area. By increasing the `ViewAngle` you effectively zoom out and vice versa. Another option to change the relative size of the graphics would be to change the distance of the initial camera position to the axes of rotation.

You can use `Export` to create an animated .gif or other type of movie, e.g.

```
Export["movie.gif", grlist];
```

[image]

This solution requires some manual tuning especially in choosing the initial view vector and the view angle. You could for example use `Manipulate` to experiment with values for these parameters.

Comment: I think most of these I had found myself, except the difference between `ViewPoint` and `ViewVector`, which was still unclear to me… thanks! However, this still requires lots of manual intervention, choosing all those values by hand. Any chance of getting closer to a nicer user experience?

Answer (score 2):

As of version 14.0, `Tour3DVideo` is introduced, and the task can be done in one line:

```
video = Tour3DVideo@p
```

[image]

The `video` can be directly exported as a MP4 file:

```
Export["rotate.mp4"] // SystemOpen
```

If you need a GIF, try:

```
Export["rotate.gif", VideoExtractFrames[video, All]] // SystemOpen
```