# An efficient circular arc primitive for Graphics3D

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

As many people have noted, the 2D graphics primitive `Circle` doesn't work in a `Graphics3D` environment (even in v10.0-v10.4, where many geometric regions were added). Several solutions to this problem have been proposed, both on [this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6526/57) and on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6495392/615464).

They all have the disadvantage that they result in either rather ugly circles or highly inefficient ones because these circles were generated using polygons with several hundreds of edges, making interactive graphics incredibly slow. Other alternatives involve the use of `ParametricPlot` which doesn't generate efficient graphics either or yield a primitive that can't be used with `GeometricTransformation`.

I would like to have a more elegant solution that creates a smooth circular arc in 3D without requiring zillions of coordinates. The resulting arc should be usable in combination with `Tube` and can be used with `GeometricTransformation`.

Comment: You know about Piegl and Tiller's book on NURBS, I presume? Their [chapter on conic arcs](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=7dqY5dyAwWkC&pg=PA281) is dandy. Alternatively, see [their earlier article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/38.35537), which is more focused on NURBS circle arcs. Their example for drawing a full circle with NURBS is also in the docs for `BSplineCurve[]`.

Comment: @J.M. No, I wasn't  aware of those guys, but thanks for the reference. I knew the example from the doc page and the Wikipedia lemma I linked to, of course, but that actually gave no clue about the extension to a general arc, which I needed to answer the [annular disk question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10960/57). I used part of [this page](http://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/Splines/NURBS.htm). I see that your ref derives the weight that I got from there in eq 7.33.

Comment: You can actually use the primitive from `ParametricPlot` with `GeometricTransformation`, [see example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6536/685). And, you can also replace `Line` with `Tube` and it works.

Comment: @VLC I wasn't saying you can't use Line with Tube, I was saying that making an arc with a few hundred Line segments is inefficient. And you can't use Tube in combination with ParametricPlot.

Comment: I found the [Taiki's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79793/1806) for a duplicate question to be simpler than the methods here.

Comment: @JessRiedel That answer doesn't meet the criteria mentioned in the question above. Since it uses DiscretizeRegion it breaks up the Circle in many segments, which is precisely what I want to avoid. It's just another version of the ParametricPlot solution mentioned in the question that I specifically did not want.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In principle, [Non-uniform rational B-splines (NURBS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline) can be used to represent conic sections. The difficulty is finding the correct set of control points and knot weights. The following function does this.

---

**UPDATE** (2016-05-22):
Added a convenience function to draw a circle or circular arc in 3D specified by three points (see bottom of post)

**EDIT** : 
Better handling of cases where end angle < start angle

---

```
ClearAll[splineCircle];
splineCircle[m_List, r_, angles_List: {0, 2 π}] :=
 Module[{seg, ϕ, start, end, pts, w, k},
   {start, end} = Mod[angles // N, 2 π];
   If[ end <= start, end += 2 π];
   seg = Quotient[end - start // N, π/2];
   ϕ = Mod[end - start // N, π/2];
   If[seg == 4, seg = 3; ϕ = π/2];
   pts = r RotationMatrix[start ].# & /@ 
     Join[Take[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1,0}, {-1, -1}, {0, -1}}, 2 seg + 1], 
      RotationMatrix[seg π/2 ].# & /@ {{1, Tan[ϕ/2]}, {Cos[ ϕ], Sin[ ϕ]}}];
   If[Length[m] == 2, 
    pts = m + # & /@ pts, 
    pts = m + # & /@ Transpose[Append[Transpose[pts], ConstantArray[0, Length[pts]]]]
   ];
   w = Join[
        Take[{1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}, 2 seg + 1], 
        {Cos[ϕ/2 ], 1}
       ];
   k = Join[{0, 0, 0}, Riffle[#, #] &@Range[seg + 1], {seg + 1}];
   BSplineCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> k, SplineWeights -> w]
 ] /; Length[m] == 2 || Length[m] == 3
```

This looks rather complex, and it is. However, the output (the only thing that ends up in the final graphics) is clean and simple:

```
splineCircle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, 3/2 π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just a single `BSplineCurve` with a few control points.

It can be used both in 2D and 3D Graphics (the dimensionality of the center point location is used to select this):

```
DynamicModule[{sc},
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[
    {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
     Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], Circle[], 
      {Thickness[0.02], Blue, 
       sc = splineCircle[m, r, {start Degree, end Degree}]
      }, 
      Green, Line[sc[[1]]], Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[sc[[1]]]
    }
  ],
  {{m, {0, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}},
  {{r, 1}, 0.5, 2},
  {{start, 45}, 0, 360},
  {{end, 180}, 0, 360}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
   Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}], Blue, 
   sc = splineCircle[{x, y, z}, r, {start Degree, end Degree}], Green,
    Line[sc[[1]]], Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[sc[[1]]]}, 
  Boxed -> False],
 {{x, 0}, -1, 1},
 {{y, 0}, -1, 1},
 {{z, 0}, -1, 1},
 {{r, 1}, 0.5, 2},
 {{start, 45}, 0, 360},
 {{end, 180}, 0, 360}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With `Tube` and various transformation functions:

```
Graphics3D[
  Table[
   {
    Hue@Random[],
    GeometricTransformation[
     Tube[splineCircle[{0, 0, 0}, RandomReal[{0.5, 4}], 
       RandomReal[{π/2, 2 π}, 2]], RandomReal[{0.2, 1}]], 
     TranslationTransform[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 3]].RotationTransform[
       RandomReal[{0, 2 π}], {0, 0, 1}].RotationTransform[
       RandomReal[{0, 2 π}], {0, 1, 0}]]
    },
   {50}
   ], Boxed -> False
  ]
```

[image]

---

**Additional uses**

I used this code to make the partial disk with annular hole asked for in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10960/57).

---

**Specification of a circle or circular arc using three points**

[The use of `Circumsphere` here was a tip by J.M.. Though it doesn't yield an arc, it can be used to obtain the parameters of an arc]

[UPDATE 2020-02-08: `CircleThrough`, introduced in v12, can be used instead of `Circumsphere` as well]

```
Options[circleFromPoints] = {arc -> False};

circleFromPoints[m : {q1_, q2_, q3_}, OptionsPattern[]] :=
Module[{c, r, ϕ1, ϕ2, p1, p2, p3, h, 
        rot = RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, Cross[#1 - #2, #3 - #2]}] &},
  {p1, p2, p3} = {q1, q2, q3}.rot[q1, q2, q3];
  h = p1[[3]];
  {p1, p2, p3} = {p1, p2, p3}[[All, ;; 2]];
  {c, r} = List @@ Circumsphere[{p1, p2, p3}];
  ϕ1 = ArcTan @@ (p3 - c);
  ϕ2 = ArcTan @@ (p1 - c);
  c = Append[c, h];
  If[OptionValue[arc] // TrueQ,
    MapAt[Function[{p}, rot[q1, q2, q3].p] /@ # &, splineCircle[c, r, {ϕ1, ϕ2}], {1}],
    MapAt[Function[{p}, rot[q1, q2, q3].p] /@ # &, splineCircle[c, r], {1}]
  ]
] /; MatrixQ[m, NumericQ] && Dimensions[m] == {3, 3}
```

Example of usage:

```
{q1, q2, q3} = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 3}];
Graphics3D[
 {
  Red,
  PointSize[0.02],
  Point[{q1, q2, q3}],
  Black,
  Text["1", q1, {0, -1}],
  Text["2", q2, {0, -1}],
  Text["3", q3, {0, -1}],
  Green,
  Tube@circleFromPoints[{q1, q2, q3}, arc -> True
  }
 ]
```

[image]

Similarly, one can define a 2D version:

```
 circleFromPoints[m : {q1_List, q2_List, q3_List}, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{c, r, ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3},
   {c, r} = List @@ Circumsphere[{q1, q2, q3}];
   If[OptionValue[arc] // TrueQ,
    ϕ1 = ArcTan @@ (q1 - c);
    ϕ2 = ArcTan @@ (q2 - c);
    ϕ3 = ArcTan @@ (q3 - c);
    {ϕ1, ϕ3} = Sort[{ϕ1, ϕ3}];
    splineCircle[c, r, 
     If[ϕ1 <= ϕ2 <= ϕ3, {ϕ1, ϕ3}, {ϕ3, ϕ1 + 2 π}]],
    splineCircle[c, r]
    ]
   ] /; MatrixQ[m, NumericQ] && Dimensions[m] == {3, 2}
```

Demo:

```
Manipulate[
 c = Circumsphere[{q1, q2, q3}][[1]];
 Graphics[
  {
   Black,
   Line[{{q1, c}, {q2, c}, {q3, c}}],
   Point[c],
   Text["1", q1, {0, -1}],
   Text["2", q2, {0, -1}],
   Text["3", q3, {0, -1}],
   Green,
   Thickness[thickness], Arrowheads[10 thickness],
   sp@circleFromPoints[{q1, q2, q3}, arc -> a]
   }, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}
  ],
 {{q1, {0, 0}}, Locator},
 {{q2, {0, 1}}, Locator},
 {{q3, {1, 0}}, Locator},
 {{a, False, "Draw arc"}, {False, True}},
 {{sp, Identity, "Graphics type"}, {Identity, Arrow}},
 {{thickness, 0.01}, 0, 0.05}
 ]
```

[image]

For versions without `Circumsphere` (i.e, before v10.0) one could use the following function to get the circle center (`c` in the code above, `r` would then be the `EuclideanDistance` between c and p1):

```
getCenter[{{p1x_, p1y_}, {p2x_, p2y_}, {p3x_, p3y_}}] := 
   {(1/2)*(p1x + p2x + ((-p1y + p2y)*
           ((p1x - p3x)*(p2x - p3x) + (p1y - p3y)*(p2y - p3y)))/
            (p1y*(p2x - p3x) + p2y*p3x - p2x*p3y + p1x*(-p2y + p3y))), 
    (1/2)*(p1y + p2y + ((p1x - p2x)*
            ((p1x - p3x)*(p2x - p3x) + (p1y - p3y)*(p2y - p3y)))/
            (p1y*(p2x - p3x) + p2y*p3x - p2x*p3y + p1x*(-p2y + p3y)))}
```

Comment: @kguler That wasn't an error. I used the square and circle as a reference. If all is well, the NURBS circle should perfectly cover the fixed circle. I made them fixed so that you can see the effect of manipulating the centre of the NURBS circle.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries great q&a -- how on Earth did you produce that last beautiful moving .gif picture in your solution :) ?  I tried `//Export["foo.gif",#,"GIF"]&` but only got a static gif, not a moving one.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin You might want to check [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/autorotating-3d-plots).

Comment: Looks like the new [`Annulus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Annulus.html) is using a similar technics as your answer. :)

Comment: @Silvia Yeah, but amazingly still no Circle in 3D.

Comment: 1. Using a little linear algebra: `{p1, p2, p3} = {q1, q2, q3}.RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, Cross[q1 - q2, q3 - q2]}]` 2. Why not use `Circumsphere[]` for `getCenter[]`? 3. Instead of using `GeometricTransformation[]`, I would suggest applying the transforms directly to the spline's control points.

Comment: @j.m. Good points. Some of the above this grew organically and I haven't done any optimization. Ad 2: I had been looking at Circumsphere, but hadn't realized that it isn't a graphics primitive itself, but that it returns a graphics primitive whose parameters I could use. A disadvantage would be that it is not backwards compatible as it is a v10 function. I'll try to come with an update.

Comment: @j.m. Finished.

Comment: Have you already seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89090), by any chance?

Comment: No, I haven't. However, with the built-in `Circumsphere` one really seems to need nothing else.

Comment: It has a certain amount of time needed, but it was a good read.

Comment: Note that, unfortunately, `CircleThrough` can only be used for 2D graphics; so, it doesn't help for the 3D case.

Answer (score 31):

Might as well... what follows is a routine that isn't as general as the routine Sjoerd gave, but gives simpler results in some cases. This is based on [work by Piegl and Tiller](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/38.35537) (see [their nice book](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=7dqY5dyAwWkC) on NURBS as well).

```
arc[center_?VectorQ, {start_?VectorQ, end_?VectorQ}] := Module[{ang, co, r},
  ang = VectorAngle[start - center, end - center];
  co = Cos[ang/2]; r = EuclideanDistance[center, start];
  BSplineCurve[{start, center + r/co Normalize[(start + end)/2 - center], end}, 
   SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
   SplineWeights -> {1, co, 1}]]
```

For example:

```
{Graphics[arc[{0, 0}, {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]],
 Graphics3D[arc[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}]]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: arc[] example]

This routine works as long as the angle determined by the arc lies in the open interval $(0,\pi)$ (an inherent limitation of the simple method), and that `EuclideanDistance[center, start] == EuclideanDistance[center, end]` (otherwise, it draws an elliptical arc). For reflex angles (that is, angles in the interval $(\pi,2\pi)$), you will have to stitch together two of these `arc[]`s properly.

(A little note: though Piegl and Tiller show in their work that one can use *negative* weights to generate an arc corresponding to a reflex angle, `BSplineCurve[]` handles negative weights poorly by default:

```
Graphics[BSplineCurve[{{-1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}, {0, Sqrt[2]}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}},
                      SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                      SplineWeights -> {1, -1/Sqrt[2], 1}], 
         PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: bad rendering of BSplineCurve[]]

but one can use an *undocumented* option setting to improve the rendering:

```
Graphics[BSplineCurve[{{-1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}, {0, Sqrt[2]}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}},
                      SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                      SplineWeights -> {1, -1/Sqrt[2], 1}],
         BaseStyle -> {BSplineCurveBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 30}}}, 
         PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: better reflex arc]

(with thanks to [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84248)))

One can also use `BSplineFunction[]` in `ParametricPlot[]`:

```
f = BSplineFunction[{{-1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}, {0, Sqrt[2]}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}}, 
                    SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
                    SplineWeights -> {1, -1/Sqrt[2], 1}];
ParametricPlot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Finally, here's how to render a unit semicircle with `BSplineCurve[]` (the generalization to the three-dimensional case is left to the reader):

```
Graphics[BSplineCurve[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}}, 
  SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1/2, 1, 1, 1}, 
  SplineWeights -> {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1}]]
```

Again, see Piegl and Tiller's work if you want to learn more about these things.

Comment: The *built-in* `BSplineFunction[]` has the error template ```BSplineFunction::invwgts= "Value of option SplineWeights -> `1` should be a rectangular array of positive numbers, with the same dimensions as the control point  array."```. Namely the weigth $w_i>0$. However, in your case, it ignored the negative weights `{1, -1/Sqrt[2], 1}`.

Answer (score 6):

This is more an extended comment than an answer. Sjoerd C. de Vries' answer is already almost perfect. However, as @J.M. already pointed out, a bit of linear algebra may improve efficiency.

1. Some time ago, I found out for myself that `RotationMatrix` is pretty slow compared to straightforwardly setting up the matrix by hand.
2. For a matrix `A`, we have that `A` multiplied from the left to a vector is the same as `Transpose[A]` multiplied from the right, so that we can replace `A.# & /@ x` with the more efficient `x.Transpose[A]`.
3. Moreover, `m + # & /@` can be vectorized by `ConstantArray[m, Length[x]] + x`.

With these small modifications and some other minor tweeks (that do not improve the readability, though), the new code looks as follows:

```
ClearAll[splineCircle2];
splineCircle2[m_List, r_, angles_List: {0., 2. π}] := 
 Module[{seg, ϕ, start, end, pts, w, k, pihalf},
   pihalf = 0.5 π;
   {start, end} = Mod[N[angles], 2. π];
   If[end <= start, end += 2. π];
   seg = Quotient[N[end - start], pihalf];
   ϕ = Mod[N[end - start], pihalf];
   If[seg == 4, seg = 3; ϕ = pihalf];
   With[{
     cseg = Cos[pihalf seg], sseg = Sin[pihalf seg],
     cϕ = Cos[ϕ], sϕ = Sin[ϕ], 
     tϕ = Tan[0.5 ϕ],
     rcs = r Cos[start], rss = r Sin[start]
     },
    pts = Join[
       Take[{{1., 0.}, {1., 1.}, {0., 1.}, {-1., 1.}, {-1., 0.}, {-1., -1.}, {0., -1.}}, 2 seg + 1],
       {{cseg - sseg tϕ, sseg + cseg tϕ}, {cseg cϕ - sseg sϕ, cϕ sseg + cseg sϕ}}
       ].{{rcs, rss}, {-rss, rcs}}
    ];
   pts = ConstantArray[m, Length[pts]] + 
     If[Length[m] == 2, 
      pts, 
      Join[pts, ConstantArray[{0.}, Length[pts]], 2]
     ];
   w = With[{c = 1./Sqrt[2.]}, 
     Join[Take[{1., c, 1., c, 1., c, 1.}, 2 seg + 1], {Cos[0.5 ϕ], 1.}]
     ];
   k = Join[{0, 0, 0}, Riffle[#, #] &@Range[seg + 1], {seg + 1}];
   BSplineCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> k, SplineWeights -> w]
   ] /; Length[m] == 2 || Length[m] == 3
```

The following test shows that this leads to a 7-fold speedup on my machine:

```
n = 2000;
mdata = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];
rdata = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {n}];
a1data = RandomReal[{0., 2 π}, {n}];
a2data = a1data + RandomReal[{0., 2 π}, {n}];
data = Transpose[{mdata, rdata, Transpose[{a1data, a2data}]}];

aa = splineCircle @@@ data; // RepeatedTiming
bb = splineCircle2 @@@ data; // RepeatedTiming
Max[Abs[aa[[All, 1]] - bb[[All, 1]]]]
Max[Abs[aa[[All, 2]] - bb[[All, 2]]]]
Max[Abs[aa[[All, 3]] - bb[[All, 3]]]]
```

> {0.78, Null}
>
> {0.11, Null}
>
> 8.88178*10^-16
>
> 0
>
> 0

Answer (score 0):

There are already some good answers here, but I will focus on brevity and simplicity in my two suggestions ... :

### **Suggestion 1 ... :**

As already noted, use a `BSplineCurve[...]`.  My only contribution to this part is brevity, and I basically took the code from the [reference documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineCurve.html#102111295)... :

> By using weights, you can make a rational B-spline, such as a circle

The code for this method is below ... :

```
Graphics3D@
 BSplineCurve[
  {{1/2, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1/2, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0}, {1/2, 0, 0}},
  SplineDegree -> 2,
  SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1}, 
  SplineWeights -> {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1}
  ]
```

[image]

### **Suggestion 2 ... :**

Intersect a `Sphere[...]` (the hollow version of a `Ball[...]` in `Mathematica`-parlance) with a plane.  I prefer using `Hyperplane[...]` simply for convenience / brevity.  Use `RegionIntersection[...]` to accomplish this suggestion...

The code for this method is below ... :

```
Region@RegionIntersection@{Hyperplane@{1, 0, 0}, 
    Sphere[]} // MacM1OpacityFix
```

[image]

This can be combined with other `Graphics3D[...]` objects using `Show[...]` (you cannot just include the region in the `Graphics3D[...]` directly, but the end-result is the same.  I prefer this method.

### **[Non-] Suggestion 3 ... :**

Finally, note that you **CAN** make a circle via an `ImplicitRegion[...]`, but if anybody else tries to then use this in `Graphics3D[...]` like I did, I'll save you some time... The following successfully generates a circle, but the resulting output cannot be used in a `Graphics3D[...]`:

```
Region@ImplicitRegion[
  {x^2 + y^2 == 1},
  {x, y}
  ]
```

[image]

***Update: This works, though ... :***

```
Region@ImplicitRegion[
  {x^2 + y^2 <= 1, z == 1},
  {x, y, z}
  ]
```

[image]

or

```
Region@ImplicitRegion[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, z == 1}, {x, y, 
    z}] // MacM1OpacityFix
```

[image]

### **NOTE - Mac M1 Bug ... :**

Note also that for whatever reason, a Mac M1 graphics-related issue prevents some of the above code from running on my machine without the fix referenced here ... : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/255291

Namely ... :

```
MacM1OpacityFix = 
  Style[#, RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "OpenGL"}] &;
```