# How to put n circles on a sphere

Tags: graphics, geometry

I have a piece of code that generates a circle on a sphere, but the problem is, this code creates only one circle. How can I change it in order to create n circles on the same sphere? Do I have to put the code in a loop?

```
    Needs["Combinatorica`"];
greatCircle[\[CurlyPhi]_, \[Theta]_, r_: 1] := 
 BSplineCurve[
  Composition[RotationTransform[\[Theta], {0, 0, 1}], 
    RotationTransform[-\[CurlyPhi], {0, 1, 
      0}]] /@ (r {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 
       0}, {-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}), SplineDegree -> 2, 
  SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1}, 
  SplineWeights -> {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1}]
With[{\[CurlyEpsilon] = 
   1*^-3 (*shrinks sphere slightly*), \[CurlyPhi] = 
   30 \[Degree] (*inclination*)}, 
 Graphics3D[{{Opacity[2/5, Blue], 
    Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1 - \[CurlyEpsilon]]}, {Directive[
     AbsoluteThickness[3], Red], greatCircle[\[CurlyPhi], 0]}}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16413/how-to-draw-a-great-circle-on-a-sphere

Comment: I was going to put this in an answer, where it would have been a lot more readable, but the question got closed me. So this will have to do. `With[{ε = 1*^-3, φ = 45 °, n = 5}, Module[{step = 360 °/n}, Graphics3D[{{Opacity[2/5, Blue], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1 - ε]}, {AbsoluteThickness[3], Red, Table[greatCircle[φ, θ], {θ, (Range[n] - 1) step}]}}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]]]` Of course you could make the table vary over `φ` rather than `θ`.

Comment: oh my God, it worked!. I it is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: The function doesn't look too hard to use: `Graphics3D[{greatCircle[0, 0], greatCircle[π/2, 0]}]`.