# Plotting cities on the Oak Island, great circle hypothesis. Does Morgantown, WV, fall on line?

Tags: plotting

Reference, [Oak Island, extending the "Alignment", possible Great Circle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235815/oak-island-extending-the-alignment-possible-great-circle), question already answered on Mathematica.

I can see illustration, but have no way to determine if Morgantown, WV, is on this plotted line.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, the OP would better put this as a comment on the original thread.

Might make it interesting, if we had some context for the question.
Treasure buried in West Virginia?

That said, I added latitude and longitude coordinates for Mogantown, WV in the following code (not particularly elegant).

```
Manipulate[
 Module[
  {rx, rz, u, v, SC, r, places, dom, ver, oak, pos, nyc, verona, 
   theso, izmir, socrota, palace, chaco, centers, mwv}, 
  ver = {48.81008221499617, 2.100137383293789};
  oak = {44.5167, -64.2992};
  dom = {31.778063322333196, 35.23541700515525};
  pos = {19.69242584751161, -98.84353081841152};
  nyc = {40.688943330006296, -74.04594759881309};
  mwv = {39.628672338323284, -79.94963581871055};
  verona = {45.43984116351433, 10.998023166145238};
  socrota = {12.551296, 54.515833};
  theso = {40.63271743626375, 22.946026906725685};
  izmir = {38.40925238535213, 27.145629351830948};
  palace = {19.42374, -99.13467};
  chaco = {36.0530, -107.9559};
  centers = {dom, ver, oak, pos, nyc, mwv, verona, theso, izmir, 
    socrota , palace, chaco };
  rx = RotationTransform[
    deg Degree, {0, 1, 
     0}] (*Rotation deg\[Degree] out of the xy plane*);
  rz = RotationTransform[\[Phi] Degree, {0, 0, 
     1}]     (*Spin around z axis*);
  {u, v} = rz@rx@{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}};
  SC[{lat_, lon_}] := 
   r {Cos[lon \[Degree]] Cos[lat \[Degree]], 
     Sin[lon \[Degree]] Cos[lat \[Degree]], Sin[lat \[Degree]]};
  r = 1;
  places = CountryData["Countries"];
  
  Column[
   {
    Show[
     Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.95], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r], 
       Map[
        Line[Map[SC, CountryData[#, "SchematicCoordinates"], {-2}]] &,
         places], {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[SC[#]] & /@ centers}},
       Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, ViewAngle -> .3, 
      ImageSize -> 600], 
     ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[\[Theta]] u + 
        Sin[\[Theta]] v,(*The great circle in \
question*){Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], 0},(*Normal unit circle*)
       RotationTransform[\[Theta], {0, 0, 
          1}] /@ {u, -u} (*Red circles at top& bottom of great \
circle*)}, {\[Theta], -Pi, Pi}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Medium], Directive[Black, Thin], 
        Directive[Red, Thin]}]],
    
    Grid[{
      {"Interesting points on/near Great Circle", SpanFromLeft, 
       SpanFromLeft},
      {},
      {"", "Latitude", "Longitude"},
      {"   Socrota", 12.551296, 54.515833},
      {"   Temple Mount", 31.77806332233319, 
       35.23541700515525}, {"   Iizmir", 38.40925238535213, 
       27.145629351830948}, {"   Thesalaniki", 40.63271743626375, 
       22.946026906725685}, {"   Verona", 45.43984116351433, 
       10.998023166145238}, {"   Versailles", 48.81008221499617, 
       2.100137383293789},
      {"   Oak Island", 44.5167, -64.2992},
      {"   New York", 40.688943330006296, -74.04594759881309},
      {"   Morgantown, WV", 39.628672338323284, -79.94963581871055},
      {"   Pyramid of the Sun", 19.69242584751161, -98.84353081841152},
      {"   Montezuma's palace", 19.42374, -99.13467},
      {"   Chaco Canyon", 36.0530, -107.9559}
      },
     Alignment -> {{Left, ".", "."}, Automatic}, 
     Dividers -> {None, {4 -> Gray}}
     ]
    }
   ]
  ],
 {{deg, 128, "Inclination"}, -180, 180, 0.05, 
  Appearance -> "Open"}, {{\[Phi], 335}, 0, 360, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Open"}
 ]
```

[image]

It does not appear to fall on the great circle discussed in the original thread.