# Forming Cone with Tube fails to work in version 9.0.1

Tags: graphics3d, bugs

I use two different radii in a `Tube` expression to draw a cone.  I know for a fact that this worked in Mathematica 8, but when I reevaluated my code in versio 9.0.1

```
Graphics3D[{CapForm["Butt"], Tube[{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 4}}, {2, 4}]}]
```

which looks like this I get a tube

[image: "Butt" gives no cone.]

while

```
Graphics3D[{CapForm[None], Tube[{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 4}}, {2, 4}]}]
```

returns open cones, which is not what I want

[image: None gives a cone but is open]

The `Help` does not indicate that any changes have been applied in version 9.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the comments.  The error has been reported.  Below a summary of Mathematica's behavior.

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.6], CapForm["Square"], #, CapForm[None], #,
CapForm["Butt"], #}] & @ Tube[{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 4}}, {2, 4}]
```

[image: Summary of CapForm error.]

Comment: The problem only exists for `CapForm["Butt"]`--the other `CapForm`s work correctly. Also, pasting the graphic generated in version 8 into version 9 yields the same result that version 9 produces on its own--that is, the expression is identical; it's just that its interpretation for display appears to differ between them.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the workaround,  I came up with another solution, but I have to admitt that 'Disk3D' had eluded me.  I will reprot this as an error to Wolfram.

Answer (score 3):

Workaround until bug is fixed:

```
pts = {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 4}};
r = {2, 4};
Disk3D[c_, d_, r_: 1] := Cylinder[{c, c + 10^-4 (c-d)}, r]
Graphics3D[{
  CapForm[None],EdgeForm[None],
  Disk3D[First@pts, pts[[2]], First@r],
  Disk3D[Last@pts, pts[[-2]], Last@r],
  Tube[pts, r]}]
```

(Is there a more pure way to make a disk in 3D that doesn't rely on fixed constant like 10^-4 that might be way too big at times?)

Comment: I described a method to make a nice smooth circle in 3D [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10958/57). Unfortunately, due to `FilledCurve` being 2D only, this circle could not be filled in 3D.

Comment: Can you try `Graphics3D[{CapForm[None], EdgeForm[None], {CapForm["Butt"], MapThread[Tube[{#1, #1}, {#2, #2}] &, {pts, r}]}, Tube[pts, r]}]` in version 9?

Comment: @J.M. Sorry, I only have v8