# How can I find incentre of a list of triangles?

Tags: geometry

I have a list of triangles.

```
{{{2, 3}, {23, 31}, {32, 19}}, {{2, 5}, {23, 33}, {32, 21}}, {{2, 
   6}, {23, 34}, {32, 22}}, {{2, 8}, {23, 36}, {32, 24}}, {{2, 
   9}, {23, 37}, {32, 25}}, {{2, 10}, {23, 38}, {32, 26}}, {{2, 
   11}, {23, 39}, {32, 27}}, {{3, 4}, {24, 32}, {33, 20}}, {{3, 
   6}, {24, 34}, {33, 22}}, {{3, 7}, {24, 35}, {33, 23}}, {{3, 
   9}, {24, 37}, {33, 25}}, {{3, 10}, {24, 38}, {33, 26}}, {{3, 
   11}, {24, 39}, {33, 27}}, {{4, 3}, {25, 31}, {34, 19}}, {{4, 
   5}, {25, 33}, {34, 21}}, {{4, 7}, {25, 35}, {34, 23}}, {{4, 
   8}, {25, 36}, {34, 24}}, {{4, 10}, {25, 38}, {34, 26}}, {{4, 
   11}, {25, 39}, {34, 27}}, {{5, 3}, {26, 31}, {35, 19}}, {{5, 
   4}, {26, 32}, {35, 20}}, {{5, 6}, {26, 34}, {35, 22}}, {{5, 
   8}, {26, 36}, {35, 24}}, {{5, 9}, {26, 37}, {35, 25}}, {{5, 
   11}, {26, 39}, {35, 27}}, {{6, 3}, {27, 31}, {36, 19}}, {{6, 
   4}, {27, 32}, {36, 20}}, {{6, 5}, {27, 33}, {36, 21}}, {{6, 
   7}, {27, 35}, {36, 23}}, {{6, 9}, {27, 37}, {36, 25}}, {{6, 
   10}, {27, 38}, {36, 26}}, {{7, 3}, {28, 31}, {37, 19}}, {{7, 
   4}, {28, 32}, {37, 20}}, {{7, 5}, {28, 33}, {37, 21}}, {{7, 
   6}, {28, 34}, {37, 22}}, {{7, 8}, {28, 36}, {37, 24}}, {{7, 
   10}, {28, 38}, {37, 26}}, {{7, 11}, {28, 39}, {37, 27}}, {{8, 
   3}, {29, 31}, {38, 19}}, {{8, 4}, {29, 32}, {38, 20}}, {{8, 
   5}, {29, 33}, {38, 21}}, {{8, 6}, {29, 34}, {38, 22}}, {{8, 
   7}, {29, 35}, {38, 23}}, {{8, 9}, {29, 37}, {38, 25}}, {{8, 
   11}, {29, 39}, {38, 27}}, {{9, 3}, {30, 31}, {39, 19}}, {{9, 
   4}, {30, 32}, {39, 20}}, {{9, 5}, {30, 33}, {39, 21}}, {{9, 
   6}, {30, 34}, {39, 22}}, {{9, 7}, {30, 35}, {39, 23}}, {{9, 
   8}, {30, 36}, {39, 24}}, {{9, 10}, {30, 38}, {39, 26}}, {{10, 
   4}, {31, 32}, {40, 20}}, {{10, 5}, {31, 33}, {40, 21}}, {{10, 
   6}, {31, 34}, {40, 22}}, {{10, 7}, {31, 35}, {40, 23}}, {{10, 
   8}, {31, 36}, {40, 24}}, {{10, 9}, {31, 37}, {40, 25}}, {{10, 
   11}, {31, 39}, {40, 27}}}
```

Now I want to find incenter of all triangles of that list.
For each triangle, I used

```
pA = {2, 3}; pB = {23, 31}; pC = {32, 19};
lr = MeshRegion[{pA, pB, pC}, Triangle[Range@3]];
r1 = RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{pA, pB}], {x, y}];
r2 = RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{pB, pC}], {x, y}];
r3 = RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{pC, pA}], {x, y}];
centerC = {x, y} /. Solve[{r1 == r2, r2 == r3}, {x, y}, Reals];
centerC = Select[centerC, RegionMember[lr, #] &][[1]]
raioC = RegionDistance[Line[{pA, pB}], centerC]
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], White, Triangle[{pA, pB, pC}], 
  PointSize[Large], Red, Point@centerC, Red, Circle[centerC, raioC]}]
```

How can I use that code with the above list?

Comment: Another possibility: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33846/insphere-for-irregular-tetrahedron/33896#33896 -- `insphere[#]["center"] & /@ pts`.

Comment: I think, this is not duplicase. Because, with one triangle, I solved. My question is a list of triangles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question [according to the OP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163217/how-can-i-find-incentre-of-a-list-of-triangles?noredirect=1#comment432429_163217) might be further clarified thus:

> I have a procedure that works on a single input. How do I apply it to a list of inputs?

The question isn't really about incenters, but being couched in a lot incentral detail, it is unlikely to help others who face exactly the same good, basic programming question, whether it is about finding triangles, or derivatives, or whatever.  (But if the question is really about finding incenters, then I think it's a duplicate.)

Methods for applying functions to lists are outlined in the guide [Applying Functions to Lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ApplyingFunctionsToLists.html).

The first step in repeatedly applying a block of code is usually to convert it to a function.  One question is whether the function is to compute the graphic or just the center and radius.  The latter seems preferable to me, but to each their own.  There are other choices.  Usually you want to localize all the variables in a `Module`. Even the symbolic variables `x` and `y` should be localized, in case you execute something like `x = 1` during your session.

```
incenterRaio[tri_] :=     
 Module[{pA, pB, pC, lr, r1, r2, r3, centerC, x, y, raioC},
  {pA, pB, pC} = tri;
  lr = MeshRegion[{pA, pB, pC}, Triangle[Range@3]];
  r1 = RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{pA, pB}], {x, y}];
  r2 = RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{pB, pC}], {x, y}];
  r3 = RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{pC, pA}], {x, y}];
  centerC = {x, y} /. Solve[{r1 == r2, r2 == r3}, {x, y}, Reals];
  centerC = Select[centerC, RegionMember[lr, #] &][[1]];
  raioC = RegionDistance[Line[{pA, pB}], centerC];
  {centerC, raioC}
  ]
```

One could also set up the function with the points as arguments:

```
incenterRaio[{pA_, pB_, pC_}] :=     
 Module[{lr, r1, r2, r3, centerC, x, y, raioC},  (* omit pA etc and first line *)
  lr = MeshRegion[{pA, pB, pC}, Triangle[Range@3]];
  ...
  {centerC, raioC}
  ]
```

But one doesn't need to overthink this before you see it's working.

### Applying a function to a single list

#### Map

[`Map` (`/@`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) is [@CarlWoll's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163219/4999).  It is the "functional programming" approach and often valued above others in this community.  For the function `incenterRaio`, it's the same: `incenterRaio /@ triangles`.

#### Table

[`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) is a personal favorite for getting the job at hand done, when I don't have to worry about code reuse or building a package.  I think it's easy for those coming from procedural programming paradigms if you think of `Table` as a for-loop that makes a list of the results.  You don't even have to convert the code block to a function.  Just make the input a variable and use the variable in the `Table` iterator.

```
incircles = Table[
  {pA, pB, pC} = tri;  (* the only change to the OP's code block *)
  lr = MeshRegion[{pA, pB, pC}, Triangle[Range@3]];
  r1 = RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{pA, pB}], {x, y}];
  r2 = RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{pB, pC}], {x, y}];
  r3 = RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{pC, pA}], {x, y}];
  centerC = {x, y} /. Solve[{r1 == r2, r2 == r3}, {x, y}, Reals];
  centerC = Select[centerC, RegionMember[lr, #] &][[1]];
  raioC = RegionDistance[Line[{pA, pB}], centerC];
  {centerC, raioC},
  {tri, triangles}]   (* Table[] will loop over the list  triangles  *)
(*
{{{23, 21}, 6}, {{23, 23}, 6}, {{23, 24}, 6}, {{23, 26}, 6}, {{23, 27}, 6}, {{23, 28}, 6},
 {{23, 29}, 6}, {{24, 22}, 6}, {{24, 24}, 6}, {{24, 25}, 6}, {{24, 27}, 6}, {{24, 28}, 6},
 {{24, 29}, 6}, {{25, 21}, 6}, {{25, 23}, 6}, {{25, 25}, 6}, {{25, 26}, 6}, {{25, 28}, 6},
 {{25, 29}, 6}, {{26, 21}, 6}, {{26, 22}, 6}, {{26, 24}, 6}, {{26, 26}, 6}, {{26, 27}, 6},
 {{26, 29}, 6}, {{27, 21}, 6}, {{27, 22}, 6}, {{27, 23}, 6}, {{27, 25}, 6}, {{27, 27}, 6},
 {{27, 28}, 6}, {{28, 21}, 6}, {{28, 22}, 6}, {{28, 23}, 6}, {{28, 24}, 6}, {{28, 26}, 6},
 {{28, 28}, 6}, {{28, 29}, 6}, {{29, 21}, 6}, {{29, 22}, 6}, {{29, 23}, 6}, {{29, 24}, 6},
 {{29, 25}, 6}, {{29, 27}, 6}, {{29, 29}, 6}, {{30, 21}, 6}, {{30, 22}, 6}, {{30, 23}, 6},
 {{30, 24}, 6}, {{30, 25}, 6}, {{30, 26}, 6}, {{30, 28}, 6}, {{31, 22}, 6}, {{31, 23}, 6},
 {{31, 24}, 6}, {{31, 25}, 6}, {{31, 26}, 6}, {{31, 27}, 6}, {{31, 29}, 6}}
*)
```

### Applying a function to two (or more) lists

Suppose you want to apply the `Graphic[..]` code to the list of `incircles`.  You also need the corresponding triangle from the list of `triangles`.  The setup is this.  Input:

```
triangles = {tri1, tri2, ...}
incircles = {cr1,  cr2, ...}
```

Desired output:

```
Out[]= {f[tri1, cr1], f[tri2, cr2], ...}
```

#### MapThread

The solution is [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html):

```
MapThread[f, {triangles, incircles}]
```

### How to make the elements of a list the arguments of a function

Now, how to construct `f`? There is one problem to address first: We want to construct `Circle[centerC, raioC]` given a list `cr` = `{centerC, raioC}`.

#### Apply

The solution is [`Apply` (`@@`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html):

```
Circle @@ {centerC, raioC}
(*  Circle[centerC, raioC]  *)
```

### Function for the graphics

One can make a function as we did above, but let's show another common way, [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html).

```
MapThread[
  Function[
   {tri, cr},  (* arguments: tri = triangle, cr = {center, radius} *)
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], White, Triangle[tri], 
     PointSize[Large], Red, Point@First@cr, Red, Circle @@ cr}, (* First@cr = center *)
    PlotRange -> {{2.`, 40.`}, {3.`, 39.`}}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
   ],
  {triangles, incircles}] //
 ListAnimate  (* optional visualization *)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer.

Comment: @toandhsp You're welcome. :)

Comment: Now I understand clearly my problem. I have just tried MapThread[Insphere, {triangles}]. A big problem is how can I make list triangles like that.

Comment: In your code, * First@cr = center *, How can I get the second? I used  `Second@cr`, I didn't get the result.

Comment: `First[cr]` is equivalent to `cr[[1]]` (see the "Details" of the doc page for `First`); use `cr[[2]]` for the second part.  `e[[...]]` is the same as `Part[e,...]`. `First` and `Last` are for convenience, I guess; they're easier to read when there's an excessive amount of `e2[[e1[[n]]]]`.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [`Insphere`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Insphere)? For example:

```
triangles = {{{2,3},{23,31},{32,19}},{{2,5},{23,33},{32,21}},{{2,6},{23,34},{32,22}}};

(Insphere /@ triangles)[[All, 1]]
```

> {{23, 21}, {23, 23}, {23, 24}}

Comment: While J.M. alluded to `Insphere[]` in his answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57828/to-inscribe-a-circle-in-a-given-triangle), it seems to me it ought to be a separate answer, since I think it's more efficient than the posted answers.