# Plotting hypersurfaces in 4D (so 3D objects)

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, geometry

I have a real algebraic variety given by the equation $x (z+v) - y (x+y)=0$ that I want to draw inside a probability simplex, so inside a tetrahedron given by the equations $x + y + z + v = 1$ and $0 < x, y, z, v < 1$.

My question is how to plot this using *Mathematica*.

I tried to simply substitute $v=1-x-y-z$ into the first equation and use counterplot or 3dplot or regionplot to achieve the result but this does not yield what I require: it does show some surface in 3D but not the simplex and strangely the z-coordinate is not at all where I thought it would be. So I guess the projection is somehow messed up by the naive substitution (I tried to replicate the problem as a projection from 3D to 2D, so onto a surface x+y+z=1 using Gram Schmidt and a proper orthogonal projection but I'm lacking intuition in order to find errors in my calculations.).

Below is a picture of what I imagine my surface should look like (roughly, just to get the idea).

[image]

I'm happy to do some more maths on paper in order to simplify my problem before throwing it at mathematica but at the moment I just don't know in what direction to go. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just a remark: in your image, the gray surface is a _2D_ object (even though it's supposed to represent a 3D object). In the end, to you want a 2D surface in 3D? Otherwise I don't think it's possible (except if you allow time as an additional parameter).

Answer (score 3):

Using an approach similar to the 4D tetrahedron insphere [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33846/insphere-for-irregular-tetrahedron/33896#33896), here's a way to project the surface from 4D to 3D.  I parametrized the surface over two of the variables (`z`, `v`).

```
proj0 = N@ Orthogonalize[IdentityMatrix[4]~Prepend~{1, 1, 1, 1}][[2 ;; 4]];
proj[pts_?VectorQ] := proj0.pts;
proj[pts_?MatrixQ] := Transpose[proj0.Transpose@pts];

dom = DiscretizeRegion[
   ImplicitRegion[v + z <= 1, {{z, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}}],
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.05}];

mr = MeshRegion[
   proj@Transpose[
     {x, y, z, v} /. 
       First@Solve[{x*(z + v) - y*(x + y) == 0, 
          x + y + z + v == 1}, {x, y}] /. 
      Thread[{z, v} -> Transpose@MeshCoordinates[dom]]],
   MeshCells[dom, 2]
   ];

Show[
 Graphics3D[
  {EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[0.], Tetrahedron[proj@IdentityMatrix[4]]}
  ],
 mr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include your definition `dom` in your answer?

Comment: @Edmund Oops.  Thanks!

Comment: That's great, thank you! Is there a way to cancel the box around it and add some names to the vertices?

Comment: Add the option `Boxed -> False` to `Graphics3D[]` or to `Show[]`.  You can add `Text[..]` as in Rahul's answer.  The vertices are at the projections of the 4D vertices, e.g. `Text[HoldForm[{1, 0, 0, 0}], proj[{1, 0, 0, 0}], offset]`, where `offset` controls how to offset the text from the point as described in the documentation for `Text`.  In 3D graphics, it is sometimes better to add a vector to the point than to use `offset`.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this using `ContourPlot3D`: Choose a mapping from 3D space $\{(p_x,p_y,p_z)\}$ to the 4D simplex $\{(x,y,z,v): x+y+z+v=1\}$, express the desired equation $x(z+v)-y(x+y)=0$ in terms of $(p_x,p_y,p_z)$, and draw its contour.

You can choose any four points to map the vertices of the simplex to, but I'll use the built-in regular tetrahedron from `PolyhedronData`.

```
vertices = PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]
xyzv[px_, py_, pz_] := 
 Evaluate@First@
   Solve[{Total[vertices {x, y, z, v}] == {px, py, pz}, 
     x + y + z + v == 1}, {x, y, z, v}]
min = Min /@ Transpose[vertices];
max = Max /@ Transpose[vertices];
Show[Graphics3D[{FaceForm[None], Tetrahedron[vertices], 
   Text["(1,0,0,0)", vertices[[1]], {-1, 0}], 
   Text["(0,1,0,0)", vertices[[2]], {0, 1}], 
   Text["(0,0,1,0)", vertices[[3]], {1, 0}], 
   Text["(0,0,0,1)", vertices[[4]], {0, -1}]}], 
 ContourPlot3D[
  Evaluate[(x (z + v) - y (x + y) == 0) /. xyzv[px, py, pz]], 
  {px, min[[1]], max[[1]]}, {py, min[[2]], max[[2]]}, {pz, min[[3]], max[[3]]}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{px, py, pz}, 
    And @@ Thread[({x, y, z, v} /. xyzv[px, py, pz]) >= 0]], 
  Mesh -> False], Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {-2, -2, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks exactly like I wanted! Great, thank so you much!
Can you also tell me whether it's possible to generalise this solution to the case when I have more than one equation defining my surface inside the simplex?

Comment: If you have two equations, you would get a curve, not a surface, right? In that case, take a look at this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5968/484 ...Three equations would give you just a point (or a finite set of points), in which case you should just use `Solve`.