# Geometry computations add-on for Mathematica?

Tags: packages, geometry, built-in-symbols, mathworld

I came across the problem of calculating the circumcenters of triangles symbolically within another algorithm (as well as possibly doing other similar geometry computations). I was hoping Mathematica would have built-in support for geometry computations like this, but the closest thing I could find was `RegionCentroid` (which of course calculates the centroid, not the circumcenter).

However, on the [Wolfram MathWorld page for Circumcenter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcenter.html) I saw there is an option to download a Mathematica notebook (just below the page title "Circumcenter"). This notebook requires the `` MathWorld`PlaneGeometry` `` package, which contains functionality to calculate circumcenters as well as tons of other useful stuff, but it apparently was removed from Mathematica (for I do not know what reason) somewhere along the line. Using the answer to this post ([Where to download the MathWorld package?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43620/where-to-download-the-mathworld-package)) and the Wayback Machine I was able to find the package, but it appears to be incompatible with Mathematica 10 anyways.

Beyond the MathWorld packages then, are there other packages that would have functionality to do things like compute circumcenters (or even better, is there built-in functionality for this that I have not found)?

I could write my own algorithm to compute a circumcenter, but this seems like a common enough geometrical computation that it and other computations like it are probably readily implemented somewhere.

Comment: The package is incompatible with any recent version of Mathematica. Current support for geometric computations is radically different and much extended over the old version of Mathematica for which the package ``MathWorld`PlaneGeometry`` was written.

Comment: @m_goldberg What do you mean by "radically different and much extended"? I am still not sure why they would remove support for what seems like a set of highly useful geometric functionality (unless you are saying that such support was not in fact removed but extended...?).

Comment: If you don't have a version of *Mathematica* with the built-in `Circumsphere[]` function, see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89090).

Answer (score 10):

The following is a built-in way of finding circumcenters:

```
gr = Graphics[{
   Circumsphere[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}],
   Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]
   }];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
center = First@Circumsphere[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]
```

> `{1/2, 1/2}`

```
gr = Graphics[{
   Circumsphere[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}],
   Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}],
   Red, PointSize[Large], Point[center]
   }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`First@Circumsphere[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]` is used because `Circumsphere` returns a `Sphere` graphics primitive. The first argument of the `Sphere` graphics primitive is the center.

Comment: Do you need to use `Cases` to extract the info?  `Circumsphere` evaluates directly to a `Sphere` outside of `Graphics`, so you could just do `In[22]:= First@Circumsphere[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]

Out[22]= {1/2, 1/2}`

Comment: @JasonB. This is a fair point, I didn't think about that. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I did not think to use graphics primitives (the approach of constructing graphics and then recovering geometry information does seem weird). However, though this is a nice solution for calculating the circumcenter, I am guessing if you wanted to calculate something more complicated like the Nagel point or the Spieker center this graphics-based approach would not work... I am still wondering if there is functionality for more general geometric computations somewhere.

Comment: I mean there is a lot more stuff pertaining to both simple geometry and computational geometry. The new stuff is mostly based on simplexes and regions built-up from meshes of simplexes. If you want to know more, go to the [Wolfram Language site](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/) and an click on Geometry.

Comment: @Grayscale The comment above was meant for you, as a response to what you were talking about in the comments to the question.