# Minimize a solution

Tags: mathematical-optimization, geometry, conditional

I have three points in a 3D space

```
A(xa,ya,za)
B(xb,yb,zb)
C(xc,yc,zc)
```

I would like to find the smallest sphere which pass `A`,`B`, and `C`.

```
(x-xo)^2+(y-yo)^2+(z-zo)^2=R^2
```

I need to obtain

```
(xo,yo,zo, R)
```

First, I consider solving the equal distance.

```
Solve[{(x - xa)^2 + (y - ya)^2 + (z - za)^2 == 
   R, (x - xb)^2 + (y - yb)^2 + (z - zb)^2 == 
   R, (x - xc)^2 + (y - yc)^2 + (z - zc)^2 == R}, {x, y, z}]
```

But I do not now how to add it as a condition of a minimization

```
Minimize[R, ?????]
```

**Update**
I just add the point that mathematica stucks on direct geometric solution

```
Solve[{(x - xa)^2 + (y - ya)^2 + (z - za)^2 == R^2,
    (x - xb)^2 + (y - yb)^2 + (z - zb)^2 == R^2,
    (x - xc)^2 + (y - yc)^2 + (z - zc)^2 == R^2, 
    Det[{{z - xa, y - ya, z - za}, {xb - xa, yb - ya, 
    zb - za}, {xc - xa, yc - ya, zc - za}}] == 0},
        {x, y, z, R}]
```

Comment: A sketch: project the three points to the plane, find their circumcircle, and then make the sphere that has that circumcircle as its great circle.

Comment: I am not a mathematica expert, I just know `Solve` and `Minimize`. But other ideas are welcome. However, I do not think mathematica can do calculate analytical circumcircle.

Comment: I believe the center of the sphere will lie in the plane containing the points A,B,C and will lie at the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of the line AB and of the line BC in that plane. That simplifies your minimization problem down to constructing that intersection.

Comment: related (I hope you realize its the same problem..) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1076177/92921

Answer (score 1):

How about this quite standard way

```
sol[{xa_, ya_, za_}, {xb_, yb_, zb_}, {xc_, yc_, zc_}] := 
    Solve[{(x0 - xa)^2 + (y0 - ya)^2 + (z0 - za)^2 == 
            R^2, (x0 - xb)^2 + (y0 - yb)^2 + (z0 - zb)^2 == 
            R^2, (x0 - xc)^2 + (y0 - yc)^2 + (z0 - zc)^2 == R^2}, {R, x0, y0},
            Reals]
```

Select the solution with R > 0

```
Minimize[R /. #, {x0, y0, z0}] & /@ 
     sol[{1, 2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}]

(*   (-\[Infinity]  {z0->-\[Infinity],x0->33/10,y0->8/5}
     (3 Sqrt[5/7])/2    {z0->-(3/14),x0->33/10,y0->8/5})   *)
```

Comment: I need the analytical solution. That's my main problem.

Comment: You can not find an analytical solution. How should  `Minimize ` decide, whether the three points line up in one line or not and R would be Infinity. You can get a general solution for R  `sa = sol[{xa, ya, za}, {xb, yb, zb}, {xc, yc, zc}] ` which is lengthy, but depends only on z0. Transfer this to C++ and then  find the minimum in zo with C++ routines for given  `{xa, ya, za}, {xb, yb, zb}, {xc, yc, zc} `.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explicit implementation of my idea in the comments. Using [Fiedler's technique](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89090) for determining the circumsphere via the [Cayley-Menger matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html):

```
CayleyMengerMatrix[pts_?MatrixQ] := With[{d = Length[pts] + 1}, 
      SparseArray[{{j_ /; j > 1, 1} :> 1, {1, k_ /; k > 1} :> 1,
                   {j_, k_} /; j != k :> ((#.#) &[pts[[j - 1]] - pts[[k - 1]]])}, {d, d}]]

CircumSphere[pts_?MatrixQ] := Module[{cv, icm, rc},
      icm = -2 Inverse[CayleyMengerMatrix[pts]]; cv = icm[[1, 2 ;;]];
      rc = First[Sqrt[Tr[icm, List]]];
      Sphere[cv.pts/Total[cv], rc/2]]

cs[{{xa_, ya_, za_}, {xb_, yb_, zb_}, {xc_, yc_, zc_}}] =
   Simplify[CircumSphere[{{xa, ya, za}, {xb, yb, zb}, {xc, yc, zc}}]]
```

where evaluating the last line will give you an explicit closed form formula (whose output I have mercifully omitted), **with no guarantees on numerical stability**. (Reformulating the resulting formula for stability is left up to you.)

Nevertheless,

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[14344, Method -> "MersenneTwister"];
            pts = TranslationTransform[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]][
                  Normalize /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {3, 3}]]];

Graphics3D[{{Opacity[2/3], Sphere @@ cs[pts]}, Triangle[pts], Sphere[pts, 0.02]},
           Boxed -> False]
```

[image: circumsphere for a 3D triangle]

Comment: Something to adjust: it doesn't work for me..

Comment: If you can give an explicit example where this doesn't work (apart from degenerate cases like collinear points, which is a known weakness of this approach), I *might* be able to fix this.

Comment: Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4em4atlet4bktfo/sphere.pdf?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/z1udyh5gx6a91p3/sphere.nb?dl=0 .

Comment: Ah, it was a variable I forgot I used. Try it now (after evaluating `Remove[cs]`).

Comment: cs[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}] outputs Sphere[{Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate}, Indeterminate]  My code works in this case.(for  @J.M.)

Comment: I said "apart from degenerate cases". ;) As you note yourself, your solution *doesn't* work to give the generic case ("but the code is running on my comp without any output during long time").

Comment: Sorry, your words do not correspond to reality.

Comment: I'll *stop responding* after this: I presume the user will add a check for degenerate cases since he says "at the end I have to implement the entire method in C++".

Answer (score 0):

In principle,

```
Minimize[{r,Exists[{x0, y0, 
z0}, {xa, ya, za} \[Element] 
 Sphere[{x0, y0, z0}, r] && {xb, yb, zb} \[Element] 
 Sphere[{x0, y0, z0}, r] && {xc, yc, zc} \[Element] 
 Sphere[{x0, y0, z0}, r]]}, r]
```

should work, but the code is running on my comp without any output  during long time. However, this works well for concrete points, e.g.

```
Minimize[{r,Exists[{x0, y0, 
z0}, {1, 2, -1} \[Element] 
 Sphere[{x0, y0, z0}, r] && {0, 0, 0} \[Element] 
 Sphere[{x0, y0, z0}, r] && {1, 1, 1} \[Element] 
 Sphere[{x0, y0, z0}, r]]}, r]
```

> $ \left\{\frac{3 \sqrt{\frac{5}{7}}}{2},\left\{r\to \frac{3 \sqrt{\frac{5}{7}}}{2}\right\}\right\}$

Comment: My problem is that I need to move the solution to a C++ code. A especial case will not work for me. At the end I have to implement the entire method in C++.

Comment: However, to finalize the question, please provide the general method (Minimize of Solve) and I will accept your answer.

Comment: @ar2015: You may try Compile and CForm to this end.

Comment: Did not understand what you mean.