# 4 circular arcs, how plot the minimal surface?

Tags: computational-geometry

By using [Sjoerd de Vries code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10957/an-efficient-circular-arc-primitive-for-graphics3d) for circular arcs:

```
ClearAll[splineCircle]; 
splineCircle[m_List, r_, angles_List: {0, 2 π}] := 
 Module[{seg, ϕ, start, end, pts, w, k}, {start, end} = 
    Mod[angles // N, 2 π]; If[end <= start, end += 2 π]; 
   seg = Quotient[end - start // N, π/2]; ϕ = 
    Mod[end - start // N, π/2]; 
   If[seg == 4, seg = 3; ϕ = π/2]; 
   pts = r RotationMatrix[start].# & /@ 
     Join[Take[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 
         0}, {-1, -1}, {0, -1}}, 2 seg + 1], 
      RotationMatrix[seg π/2].# & /@ {{1, 
         Tan[ϕ/2]}, {Cos[ϕ], Sin[ϕ]}}]; 
   If[Length[m] == 2, pts = m + # & /@ pts, 
    pts = m + # & /@ 
      Transpose[
       Append[Transpose[pts], ConstantArray[0, Length[pts]]]]]; 
   w = Join[
     Take[{1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}, 
      2 seg + 1], {Cos[ϕ/2], 1}]; 
   k = Join[{0, 0, 0}, Riffle[#, #] &@Range[seg + 1], {seg + 1}]; 
   BSplineCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> k, 
    SplineWeights -> w]] /; Length[m] == 2 || Length[m] == 3

g1 = Graphics3D[
   Table[{Hue@0.1, 
     GeometricTransformation[
      Tube[splineCircle[{0, 0, 0}, 1, {0, 3.141592653589}], 
       1/12], {-1, 1, 1}]}, {1}], Boxed -> False];
g2 = Graphics3D[
   Table[{Hue@0.1, 
     GeometricTransformation[
      Tube[splineCircle[{0, -1, 0}, 1, {0, 3.141592653589}], 1/12], 
      RotationTransform[Pi, {1, 0, 1}]]}, {1}], Boxed -> False];
g3 = Graphics3D[
   Table[{Hue@0.1, 
     GeometricTransformation[
      Tube[splineCircle[{0, -1, -2}, 1, {0, 3.141592653589}], 1/12], 
      RotationTransform[Pi, {1, 0, 1}]]}, {1}], Boxed -> False];
g4 = Graphics3D[
   Table[{Hue@0.1, 
     GeometricTransformation[
      Tube[splineCircle[{0, 0, -2}, 1, {0, 3.141592653589}], 
       1/12], {-1, 1, 1}]}, {1}], Boxed -> False];
g4 = Show[g1, g2, g3, g4]
```

I plotted these four circular arcs:

[image: bent circle]

How can I make a [minimal surface](http://bugman123.com/MinimalSurfaces/index.html) that describes both the space inside it, and outside it stretching out to infinity? The minimal surface should describe the object as a whole and not the four arcs individually.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.indiana.edu/~minimal/archive/web/mathematica.html

Comment: No I have not seen it before.

Comment: It's linked in the page you referenced

Comment: There is now a solution at the generalized question [Can Mathematica solve Plateau's problem (finding a minimal surface with specified boundary)?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72203/can-mathematica-solve-plateaus-problem-finding-a-minimal-surface-with-specifie)

Comment: Sorry, I would like to retract my close vote. This question asks for the minimal surface to extend beyond the boundary too.

Comment: @MatsGranvik, Any News on that Topic?

Comment: @Louis Not really.