# Find initial surface to minimize between two close curves

Tags: mathematical-optimization, differential-geometry, boundary-conditions

I have two close curves in space defined by $g$ and $h$ with:

```
Px[t_, A_, p_] := ((\[Pi] - t) t (p \[Pi] (\[Pi] - 2 t)^2 + 16 A (\[Pi] - t) t))/\[Pi]^4
X[t_, a_, px_] := If[t <= \[Pi], Px[t, a, px], -Px[t - \[Pi], a, px]]

Py[t_, A_, \[Epsilon]_] := ((\[Pi] - 2 t) (256 A (\[Pi] - t)^2 t^2 (9 \[Pi]^2 - 16 \[Pi] t + 16 t^2) + (\[Pi] - 4 t)^2 (3 \[Pi] - 4 t)^2 (3 \[Pi]^2 + 38 \[Pi] t - 38 t^2) \[Epsilon]))/(27 \[Pi]^7)
Y[t_, b_, \[Epsilon]_] := If[t <= \[Pi], Py[t, b, \[Epsilon]], Py[2 \[Pi] - t, b, \[Epsilon]]]

Pz[t_, A_, p_] := ((\[Pi] - 2 t) (\[Pi] - t) t (3 p \[Pi] (\[Pi] - 4 t)^2 (3 \[Pi] - 4 t)^2 + 256 A (\[Pi] - t) t (9 \[Pi]^2 - 16 \[Pi] t + 16 t^2)))/(27 \[Pi]^7)
Z[t_, c_, pz_] := If[t <= \[Pi], Pz[t, c, pz], Pz[t - \[Pi], c, pz]]

g[t_] := {X[t, 2, 1], Y[t, 1, .1], Z[t, 1, 2]}
h[t_] := {-Y[t, 1, .1], X[t, 2, 1], Z[t, 1, 2]}

ParametricPlot3D[{g[t], h[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image: boundary curves]

I would now want to build the minimal surface defined by those boundaries. But I have trouble adapting [this solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72256/16127) to a situation where the initial surface is not a `Disk[]` but an `Annulus[]`.

Is it easy to adapt, or do I miss something topologically sneaky?
How do I construct this minimal surface?

Comment: Would it be appropriate to ask here how to plot the surface defined by each of these lines in 3D space -e.g the one defined by g[t], or would I need to start a new question?

Comment: @GerardF123 I'm not sure I'm getting your point. If you're strictly asking about `g[t]` then it is not a surface that it defines but a *line* (the blue one I think). If you need the surface that is an interpolation between `h` and `g`, then your answer has been given by [Ulrich](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180980/16127) below. If it is the minimal surface you need, then see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72256/16127) I've pointed to. Tell me if any of these suit :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I was getting at is that g[t] looks to me like the outline of the blade of a propeller of a ship. I wanted to draw that surface in.

Comment: @GerardF123 Okay I get it (it turns out you're right btw). Then I would define `h(t)  = g(t-)` or something like this (it is like computing the interpolation between the curve and a delayed value of itself, try  or other values), then use the result as a starting point for the minimization procedure described [there](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72256/16127). Does this make sense to you? :)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an initial surface with an easy interpolation:

```
Show [ParametricPlot3D[{g[t], h[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
ParametricPlot3D[u g[t] + (1 - u) h[t] , {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {u, 0, 1}],Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Haha! How simple this was indeed XD Thank you :) For an unclear reason: this surface is not closed (there is a rupture region close to 0), is there any reason for this? Any way to make it close again?

Comment: I although recognized "the hole". Perhaps options MaxRecursion, PlotPoints might help.

Comment: For me it seems to be a meshing problem of `ParametricPlot3D` . If you plot the mesh "by hand" everything is ok: `Show[Table[
  ParametricPlot3D[
     Evaluate[ # g[t] + (1 - #) h[t]] , {t, 0, 2 \[Pi] } ] &[u], {u, 
   0, 1, .1}],
 Table[ParametricPlot3D[
     Evaluate[ u g[#] + (1 - u) h[#]] , {u, 0, 1 } ] &[t], {t, 0, 
   2 Pi , 2 Pi/20.}], PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False
 ]`

Comment: weird behaviour, but ok why not :\