# Higher order Laplacian flows

Tags: differential-equations, geometry, computational-geometry, differential-geometry

Given disjoint surfaces $q_i$ in 3D and their 1D boundary curves $\partial q_i = \gamma_i$, I seek a surface $p$ that joins the $q_i$, where $p \cup q_i$ forms a (piecewise) $C^k$ surface that minimizes some energy functional.

For $k = 0$, this reduces to [Plateau's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau%27s_problem) and one only needs the $\gamma_i$. There are fantastic answers to this problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72203/can-mathematica-solve-plateaus-problem-finding-a-minimal-surface-with-specifie).

For example let my surfaces $q_i$ be the following open tubes:

```
n = 20;
mr = MeshRegion[
   Join[
    Append[-1.0] /@ CirclePoints[.25, n],
    Append[-0.5] /@ CirclePoints[.25, n]
    ],
   {
    Polygon[Range[n]],
    Polygon[Partition[Flatten[Riffle[Partition[Range[n], 2, 1, 1], Range[n] + n]], 3]],
    Polygon[Partition[Flatten[Riffle[Partition[Range[n] + n, 2, 1, 1], RotateLeft[Range[n]]]], 3]]
    }
 ];
mr = DiscretizeRegion[
  Region`Mesh`MeshRegionJoin[mr, 
   TransformedRegion[mr, RotationTransform[Pi/2, {0, -1, 0}]]], 
  PlotTheme -> "Default"]
```

[image]

Let's connect them with some (open) surface:

```
bd = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mr], Region`InternalBoundaryEdges[mr]];
conv = RegionBoundary[ConvexHullMesh[MeshCoordinates[bd]]];
dfs = RegionDistance[InfinitePlane[MeshCoordinates[#][[1 ;; 3]]]] & /@ ConnectedMeshComponents[bd];
centroids = PropertyValue[{conv, 2}, MeshCellCentroid];
joint = MeshRegion[
   MeshCoordinates[conv],
   Pick[MeshCells[conv, 2], 
    Thread[Greater[Min /@ Transpose[Through[dfs[centroids]]], 10^-12.]]]
   ];
joint = DiscretizeRegion[joint, MaxCellMeasure -> {2 -> .001}]
```

[image]

We can use [`areaGradientDescent`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158356/4346) to modify the joint, leading to a $C^0$ solution through gradient flow:

```
Show[
  MeshRegion[mr, MeshCellStyle -> {0 -> None, 1 -> None, 2 -> GrayLevel[.8]}],
  areaGradientDescent[joint, 1, 1]
]
```

[image]

I seek to find stationary surfaces of higher order Laplacian flows

$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = \Delta^{k+1}_M p. $$

For example, some higher order results will look like the following ([source](http://www.pmp-book.org/download/slides/Smoothing.pdf)):
[image]

**How can I incorporate the appropriate boundary conditions into a method such as `areaGradientDescent` to achieve a $C^k$ result?**

Comment: Dear Greg, something similar to the second example can be obtained by minimizing the Willmore-like energy $\int_{\mathcal{S}} |\Delta p|^2 \, \omega_{\mathcal S}$ subject to Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions. One can compute local minimizers with a projected $H^2$-gradient flow on the manifold of surfaces satisying the boundary conditions. I implemented this for my research, but it is a bit heavy and contains a _lot_ of self-written Mathematica code.

Comment: The appropriate energy for the third example might be $\int_{\mathcal{S}} |\operatorname{d} \! \Delta p|^2 \, \omega_{\mathcal{S}}$ and one could apply a third boundary condition (something like the second normal derivatives). Projected $H^3$-gradient flow might be an option, but the Gram matrices to invert would probably enormous condition number. I am not sure whether that would work out with my setting with direct solvers as I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: If you are deeply interested, I might try to post at least some code for a discrete Willmore energy (along with its derivative) and for a $H^2$-inner product.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yes, I realized shortly after posting that this was going to be much more involved than I first thought. I contemplated taking down the question.

Comment: I'd be curious to see the code you mentioned, as long as it's not too much trouble.