# Understanding syntax of `FindArgMin`

Tags: mathematical-optimization

In this post [Can Mathematica solve Plateau's problem (finding a minimal surface with specified boundary)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72203/can-mathematica-solve-plateaus-problem-finding-a-minimal-surface-with-specifie) (8 years ago) I found a call to `FindArgMin` which is unclear to me.

In the answer of @ybeltukov (unfortunately he seems to be actual inactive in stackexchange, that's why I ask a new question) I found in the first example this line of code:

`v[[pts]] = First@FindArgMin[area[vars], {vars, vc[[pts]]},...];`

where

- `vars` is a onedimensional list of unknowns `{$1,$2,...}`

and

- `vc[[pts]]` is a list of known 3D-points `{{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},..}`.

**The argumentlist `{vars, vc[[pts]]}` in the function call `FindArgMin` seems unusual to me.**

Instead I would have expected the form **Transpose[{vars, vc[[pts]]}]**:

`v[[pts]] = First@FindArgMin[area[vars], Transpose[{vars, vc[[pts]]}], ...];`

Here the `vars` would be implicit defined as lists according to the startingvalues  `vc[[pts]]` (see documentation `FindMinimum` *...If the starting point for a variable is given as a list, the values of the variable are taken to be lists with the same dimensions*)

My questions:

- Why does first variant `{vars, vc[[pts]]}` work?
- Why doesn't second variant `Transpose[{vars, vc[[pts]]}]` work?
- Where can I find more detailed documentation of `FindArgMin`

Thanks!

Comment: `findargmin` or `findminarg` ?

Comment: Thanks I meant `FindArgMin`