# Triangular mesh of random points on a sphere

Tags: graphics3d, mesh, generative-art

My employer has a new logo (shown below). I do not have information on how this was created (as it was done by an outside company), though I'm fairly sure it was not done in any formal mathematical way:

[image: Sample Logo]

It appears to be a triangular mesh of randomly spaced points, projected onto a sphere (at least to my eye, the points seem randomly distributed). I'd like to create something like this in *Mathematica* using built-in commands.

My first attempt was to generate a list of random points:

```
SeedRandom[10220];

pts = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {200, 2}];
```

And then generate a `DelaunayMesh`:

```
d = DelaunayMesh[pts];
h = HighlightMesh[d, {Style[0, Directive[PointSize[Large], Darker[Green]]],
                  Style[1, Directive[Darker[Green]]], Style[2, Opacity[0]]}];
```

[image: Delaunay mesh]

And map this texture onto a sphere:

```
sphere = SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Mesh -> None, TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, 1 - #4} &), 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[h]], Lighting -> "Neutral", 
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Sphere]

This is going in the right direction, but I'm hoping for a way to do this more efficiently.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems to me that the logo has three semitransparent layers of triangle meshes.

One can start with discretized sphere

```
reg = DiscretizeGraphics[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.8}]
```

[image]

Or with Simon's `Geodesate`. Then the function for disks in 3D is helpful

```
disk[pos_, {nx_, ny_, nz_}, r_, n_: 16] := With[{θ = ArcTan[Sqrt[nx^2 + ny^2], nz], 
  φ = ArcTan[nx, ny]}, Polygon@Table[pos + r {Cos[α] Cos[φ] Sin[θ] - Sin[α] Sin[φ], 
        Cos[φ] Sin[α] + Cos[α] Sin[φ] Sin[θ], -Cos[α] Cos[θ]}, {α, 2. π/n, 2 π, 2. π/n}]];
```

Several functions to draw randomly oriented mesh on sphere, disks on vertices and opacity sphere:

```
mesh[m_, z_] := GeometricTransformation[{Gray, 
   Normal@GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates@reg, MeshCells[reg, 1]] /. 
    Line[{a_, b_}] :> Line@Table[Normalize[a t + b (1 - t)], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]}, {First@
    QRDecomposition@m, {0, 0, z}}]
disks[m_, z_] := GeometricTransformation[{EdgeForm@Gray, 
   Glow@RGBColor[0.6, 0.75, 0.25], Black, 
   disk[#, #, 0.03] & /@ MeshCoordinates@reg}, {First@
    QRDecomposition@m, {0, 0, z}}]
sphere[op_, z_] := {Opacity@op, Glow@White, Sphere[{0, 0, z - 0.01}, 1.01]};
ball[z_] := {mesh[#, z], disks[#, z + 0.01]} &@RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {3, 3}];
```

Finally, we combine three randomly oriented layers with opacity and different z-position

```
Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[{sphere[1, 0], ball[0.02], sphere[0.2, 0.04],
    ball[0.06], sphere[0.2, 0.08], ball[0.10]}, 
  ScalingTransform[{0.7, 1, 1}]], Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 300, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}, ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}]
```

[image]

The result looks similar to the logo.

Comment: +1 The result looks *better than* the logo!

Comment: Nice observation and execution!

Answer (score 12):

Quite long since there are arcs not lines, here is the code for them:

[An efficient circular arc primitive for Graphics3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10994/5478)

```
disk = Scale[Sphere[{0, 0, 1.02}, .05], {1, 1, .2}];

Composition[
  Graphics3D[{#, Opacity@.2, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 500, 
    Lighting -> "Neutral"] &
  ,
  {
   Green, GeometricTransformation[disk, RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, First@#}]], 
   Gray, arc[{0, 0, 0}, #]
  } & /@ # &
  ,
  Extract[First@#, List /@ Last@#] &
  ,
  {
    Table[
     RotationMatrix[RandomReal[.7], RandomReal[1, 3]].p, {p, 
      First@#}], Composition[
      DeleteDuplicates,
      Sort /@ # &,
      Join @@ # &,
      # /. Polygon -> (Partition[{##, #}, 2, 1] & @@ # &) &
      ]@Last[#]} &
  ,
  {
    MeshCoordinates[#],
    MeshCells[#, 2]} &
  ,
  DiscretizeGraphics[#, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.6}] &
  ][Sphere[]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

A quick hack:

```
With[{mesh = 
   DiscretizeGraphics@PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Edges"]},
 Show[
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[1/2], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.999]}, 
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, Boxed -> False],
  MeshPrimitives[mesh, 0] /. 
   Point[p_] :> 
    Graphics3D[{Green, EdgeForm[None], 
      MeshPrimitives[
       DiscretizeRegion@
        RegionIntersection[Sphere[], Ball[Normalize@p, 1/20]], 2]}, 
     Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}],
  Graphics3D[{Green, Thick, 
    MeshPrimitives[mesh, 1] /. 
     Line[{a_, b_}] :> 
      Line[Table[Normalize[t a + (1 - t) b], {t, 0, 1, 1/50}]]}]
  ]]
```

> [image]

For random mesh, one could use randomly sampled points on a sphere and construct either `DelaunayMesh` or `ConvexHullMesh` from point set and use `BoundaryMesh` of that, but purely randomly sampled points don't actually produce aesthetic results. Thus, I use a truncated icosahedron data as an example.

**EDIT**

Inspired by ybeltukov, here's one with just a different `mesh`,

```
mesh = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.8}]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 9):

Not quite what you asked for, but here is a non-random approximation:

```
Needs["PolyhedronOperations`"]

Graphics3D[{
  Style[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.95], Opacity[0.5], Lighting -> None, Glow[White]],
  FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Darker@Green], PointSize[Large], Darker@Green,
  N[Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "Faces"], 2]] /.
   p_Polygon :> {p, Point[Flatten @@ p]}},
 Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It took a while from the first time I saw this question, but only because I only realized now that I had eventually built all the tools I thought I needed. Thus, this will link to a lot of my previous answers.

First, I'll use the [Lloyd algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/168139) to generate a bunch of equidistributed points:

```
n = 50; (* number of points *)
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1337, Method -> "MersenneTwister"];
            sp = Normalize /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, 3}]];

With[{maxit = 45, (* maximum iterations *)
      tol = 0.001 (* distance tolerance *)}, 
     lp = FixedPoint[Function[pts, 
                     Block[{ch, polys, verts, vor},
                           ch = ConvexHullMesh[pts];
                           verts = MeshCoordinates[ch];
                           polys = First /@ MeshCells[ch, 2];
                           vor = Normalize[Cross[verts[[#2]] - verts[[#1]], 
                                                 verts[[#3]] - verts[[#1]]]] &
                                 @@@ polys;
                           SphericalPolygonCentroid[vor[[#]]] & /@ 
                           ch["VertexFaceConnectivity"]]], sp, maxit, 
                     SameTest -> (Max[MapThread[cosDistance, {#1, #2}]] < tol &)]];
```

(The associated auxiliary routines will lengthen this answer, so just refer to my previous answer to get them.)

From these points, generate the convex hull and extract the corresponding points and edges:

```
ch = ConvexHullMesh[lp];
pts = MeshCoordinates[ch];
edges = First /@ MeshCells[ch, 1];
```

Finally, to render the picture, we need two NURBS-based primitives:

```
(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10994 *)
arc[center_?VectorQ, {start_?VectorQ, end_?VectorQ}] := Module[{ang, co, r},
  ang = VectorAngle[start - center, end - center];
  co = Cos[ang/2]; r = EuclideanDistance[center, start];
  BSplineCurve[{start, center + r/co Normalize[(start + end)/2 - center], end}, 
   SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
   SplineWeights -> {1, co, 1}]]

(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128496 *)
sphericalCap[{θ_, φ_}, α_] := With[{c = Cos[α/2]},
         Style[BSplineSurface[Map[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, 
                                  Append[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} Sin[φ], Cos[φ]]}], 
               Map[Function[pt, Append[#1 pt, #2]],
                   {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}}] & @@@
                   {{0, 1}, {Sin[α/2]/c, 1}, {Sin[α], Cos[α]}}], 
               SplineClosed -> {False, True}, SplineDegree -> 2, 
               SplineKnots -> {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                               {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1}}, 
               SplineWeights -> Outer[Times, {1, c, 1}, {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1}]], 
               BSplineSurface3DBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 25}}]]
```

Now, generate the picture:

```
Graphics3D[{{ColorData["Legacy", "Honeydew"], 
             Tube[arc[{0, 0, 0}, 0.98 pts[[#]]], 1/150] & /@ edges}, 
            {ColorData["Legacy", "ForestGreen"], Glow[ColorData["Legacy", "Chartreuse"]],
             EdgeForm[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1/4],
                                ColorData["Legacy", "CobaltGreen"]]], 
             sphericalCap[{ArcTan @@ Most[#], ArcCos[Last[#]/Norm[#]]}, π/60] & /@ pts}},
           Background -> ColorData["Legacy", "Gainsboro"],
           Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: spherical network]