# Drawing circular patches around arbitrary points on a sphere

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I am trying to draw circular patches of given angular radii around arbitrary points on a sphere. I am able to use, for example,

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi/3}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Opacity[0.7]}, 
                Mesh -> None]
```

and

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, (2 Pi)/3, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Opacity[0.7]},
                Mesh -> None]
```

to create angular patches of (angular) radius $\pi/3$ around the north and south poles of the sphere, respectively, but what if I want to create two patches around two *arbitrary* points on the surface of the sphere, and then draw in the rest of the sphere in some other background color? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Show[
 SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, Mesh -> None,  RegionFunction -> 
        Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, Norm[{x, y, z} - {1, 1, 0}] > 1], PlotStyle -> Red], 
 SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, Mesh -> None, RegionFunction -> 
        Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, Norm[{x, y, z} - {1, 1, 0}] < 1], PlotStyle -> Blue]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still digging into the specifics of RegionFunction and its implementation in your answer, but it seems as though I can control the radius of the circular patch by changing the inequality threshold value and the point about which the patch is centered by changing the constant vector ({1,1,0} in your example).

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast yep, that's it :)

Comment: Just for future reference (this can be added into the answer above), `Norm[{x,y,z}-{x1,y1,z1}] < c` defines a ball of radius c centered at (x1,y1,z1). It is, to me, easier to define the center of the ball to be on the surface of the sphere, so (x1,y1,z1) = R(sin\theta cos\phi, sin\theta sin\phi, cos\theta). Then, to get a circular patch with angular radius \gamma centered at (\theta, \phi) (or, equivalently, (x1,y1,z1)), the radius of the ball (with center (x1,y1,z1)) should be c = R \sqrt{ 2(1 - cos\gamma) }.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a routine that renders a spherical cap on a unit sphere as a NURBS surface:

```
sphericalCap[{θ_, φ_}, α_] := With[{c = Cos[α/2]},
         Style[BSplineSurface[Map[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, 
                                  Append[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} Sin[φ], Cos[φ]]}], 
               Map[Function[pt, Append[#1 pt, #2]],
                   {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}}] & @@@
                   {{0, 1}, {Sin[α/2]/c, 1}, {Sin[α], Cos[α]}}], 
               SplineClosed -> {False, True}, SplineDegree -> 2, 
               SplineKnots -> {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                               {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1}}, 
               SplineWeights -> Outer[Times, {1, c, 1}, {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1}]], 
               BSplineSurface3DBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 25}}]]
```

Examples:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.7, Black], sphericalCap[{0, 0}, π/6]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: an inky cap]

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom["spherecaps"];
            Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Table[{Append[RandomColor[], 2/3], 
                        sphericalCap[{RandomReal[{0, 2 π}], RandomReal[{0, π}]}, 
                                     RandomReal[{0, π/4}]]}, {10}]}]]
```

[image: various colored spherical caps]

```
Graphics3D[{Directive[EdgeForm[], GrayLevel[1/5],
                      Glow[Blend[{Brown, Yellow}, 1/4]], Specularity[Gray, 25]], 
            sphericalCap[{ArcTan @@ Most[#], ArcCos[Last[#]]},
                         ArcCos[(80 + 9 Sqrt[5])/109]/2] & /@ 
            N[PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]/
              PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Circumradius"]]}, 
           Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: spherical caps on a truncated icosahedron]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way using [`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) and [`MeshShading`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html) that generalized to any number of points.

```
pts = Normalize /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 3}];
angles = Table[{Pi/3}, Length@pts];
SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 MeshFunctions -> 
  Table[With[{v0 = v0}, 
    Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ}, 
     VectorAngle[{x, y, z}, v0]]], {v0, pts}],
 Mesh -> angles,
 MeshShading -> {{Black, Black}, {Black, Automatic}},
 BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

More random points, random angles:

```
SeedRandom[7];
pts = Normalize /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 3}];
angles = RandomReal[0.66, {Length@pts, 1}];
shading = ReplacePart[
   ConstantArray[Black, Table[2, Length@pts]], 
   Table[-1, Length@pts] -> Automatic];
SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotPoints -> 50, 
 MeshFunctions -> 
  Table[With[{v0 = v0}, 
    Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ}, 
     VectorAngle[{x, y, z}, v0]]], {v0, pts}],
 Mesh -> angles,
 MeshShading -> shading,
 BoundaryStyle -> None, MeshStyle -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had already accepted the first answer, as it worked for my purposes, but I definitely appreciate you taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast You're welcome! Sometimes you'll find people giving advice to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer.  Not having an accepted answer encourages other to take a look to see if they can do better.  Also, since [our active users are found all around the world](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1255/4999), which is really cool, imo, some may not get a chance to view your question until well after you've posted it.  But feel free to accept whichever answer you think is best whenever you want.