# How to distribute points on a Sphere[] cap from a normal distribution?

Tags: regions, random, distributions, geometry

I was wondering if one could distribute points on a "cap" of a sphere, following a normal distribution of the points instead of a uniform distribution. This normal could be centered at the cap. Maybe one can use [`SpherePoints[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpherePoints.html)?

By "cap" I mean that we select only these points within a radius of some reference point. For instance, using the case for uniform points (from [Carl Woll's answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209829/is-there-a-way-to-randomly-distribute-points-within-a-circle-on-the-surface-of-a)):

```
SeedRandom[1]
numberofPoints = 1000;
radiusofCap = .8;
ctr = RandomPoint[Sphere[]];
pts = RandomPoint[
   RegionIntersection[Ball[ctr, radiusofCap], Sphere[]], 
   numberofPoints];
Graphics3D[{Red, Point@pts, White, Opacity[.5], Sphere[]}]
```

We get:

[image]

How could we extend this so that the points are normal-distributed? A solution might be in the form:

```
myNormalCapPoints[sphereRadius_, capRadius_, numberofPoints_, std_] :=
```

Where we take the desired sphere and cap radius, then select a point on the sphere (randomly perhaps?), and generate the normal-distributed points around it with some standard deviation from the reference point.

Thanks!

**Note/update 1**: It would be like a 2D gaussian cloud of points on the surface of the sphere (at the "cap").

Comment: What do you mean by normal distribution on the sphere? What comes closest to this might be the [spherical von Mises-Fisher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises–Fisher_distribution).

Comment: Very interesting, I was not aware of this distribution but it seems that this is what I'd be looking for (I guess except for selecting points within the cap). However, the distribution seems a bit alien to me, I'll try to understand it better. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13042) contains an implementation of a von Mises-Fisher generator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here I randomly rotate points away from the pole by a distance along the surface that is drawn from a truncated normal distribution. I hope this is close to what you need:

```
n = 1000;
capc = 0.4; (* Pi/2: cover hemisphere, Pi: cover the whole thing *)
dist = TruncatedDistribution[{-capc, capc}, NormalDistribution[0, 2]];
cvals = RandomVariate[dist, n];
dirs = Append[#, 0] & /@ RandomPoint[Circle[], n];
newpts = MapThread[RotationTransform[#1, #2][{0, 0, 1}] &, {cvals, dirs}];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Sphere[], Opacity[1], Point[newpts]}]
```

[image: sphere cap normal distribution]

Comment: .@flinty this is great! And a very simple way to have a "cap" from the truncated distribution.

Comment: It should also work with other distributions and if you vary the standard deviation. If you want to move the cap to a different point other than {0,0,1} you should be able to rotate all the points after generating them first at {0,0,1} then applying a RotationTransform. Also if you increase the mean of the NormalDistribution from 0 to say 40, then you get a ring of points instead.

Comment: .@flinty, with the code as it is, it seems that varying the mean/std does not change the distribution of points. Do you know why?

Comment: It does, you just have to increase the mean / stddev by quite a lot because of the truncation. Try replacing `NormalDistribution[0, 2]` with `NormalDistribution[0, 0.1]` and you'll see the difference. Same with `NormalDistribution[80, 2]`

Comment: Ohh, I see! I was setting things like `NormalDistribution[0, 20000]` with no perceptible change. But I see one has to decrease std instead (relative to the mean). I also see the ring effect you mention. Thanks!