# Capturing mesh information

Tags: mesh

### Mesh information

Using the helpful tips from [Triangular mesh of random points on a sphere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73354/triangular-mesh-of-random-points-on-a-sphere), it's easy to generate solids:

```
reg = DiscretizeGraphics[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 5], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 15}]

MeshCellCount[reg]
```

The interrogation tab provides useful information, but it would be helpful if the data could be captured in a text format.

### Question

How can the information in the information tab (shown below) be harvested with a script?

### Screen capture

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's anything particularly special in the mesh info tab. All of it can be found with various functions which I've encapsulated below:

```
meshinfo[mesh_] := {{"Embedding Dimension", RegionEmbeddingDimension[#]},
    {"Geometric Dimension", RegionDimension[#]},
    {"Vertex Cells" , MeshPrimitives[#, 0] // Length},
    {"Edge Cells" , MeshPrimitives[#, 1] // Length},
    {"Face Cells" , MeshPrimitives[#, 2] // Length},
    {"Volume Cells" , MeshPrimitives[#, 3] // Length},
    {"Area", Area[#]},
    {"Region Bounds", RegionBounds[#]},
    {"Region Centroid", RegionCentroid[#]}} &@mesh

meshinfo[reg] // Grid

Association[Rule @@@ meshinfo[reg]]
```

Comment: (Here) `MeshPrimitives[#, 0] // Length` == `VertexCount[MeshConnectivityGraph[reg]]`,  
`MeshPrimitives[#, 1] // Length` == `EdgeCount[MeshConnectivityGraph[reg]]`, and `MeshPrimitives[#, 2] // Length` == `Length@FindCycle[MeshConnectivityGraph[reg], {3}, All]`

Comment: You can use `MeshCellCount` instead of listing out and counting all primitives.