# How to draw an interactive, mouse clickable, 3D Bloch sphere?

Tags: plotting, dynamic, eventhandler

A 3D Bloch (Poincaré) sphere is nicely shown in [this wolfram demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/QubitsOnThePoincareBlochSphere/).
However, in that example, it is not possible to mouse select a point on the sphere  and directly get the corresponding qubit representation.

How can we do something like this with Mathematica?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is an attempt to draw a 3D Bloch sphere, on which we can select a point by simply clicking on it with the mouse and obtaining the corresponding qubit representation.
In the code I made use of [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs)' [MaTeX package](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX) to draw the labels in LaTeX (not necessary, but better looking) and [Sjoerd C. de Vries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/57/sjoerd-c-de-vries)' [`splineCircle`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10958/27539) to draw the 3D arcs (the above functions are therefore necessary to run the following code).

## Result

[image]

---

## Code sections

### Pretty printing qubit states:

We start by defining a function that takes as input the amplitudes of the state, and prints in output the state in a nice-looking form:

```
ClearAll@qubitPrettyPrint;
Options[qubitPrettyPrint] = {normalized -> False, magnification -> 2, 
   prefix -> ""};
qubitPrettyPrint[c1_, c2_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 If[! TrueQ@OptionValue@normalized,
  MaTeX[
   StringTemplate[
     "`3`\\left(`1`\\right)\\left|0\\right\\rangle + \\left(`2`\\right)\\left|1\\right\\rangle"][
    ToString@TeXForm[c1], ToString@TeXForm[c2], 
    ToString@OptionValue@prefix
    ],
   Magnification -> OptionValue@magnification
   ],
  With[{nCoefficients = Normalize[{c1, c2}]},
   MaTeX[
    StringTemplate[
      "`3`\\left(`1`\\right)\\left|0\\right\\rangle +\\left(`2`\\right)\\left|1\\right\\rangle"][
     Sequence @@ (ToString@*TeXForm /@ nCoefficients), 
     ToString@OptionValue@prefix
     ],
    Magnification -> OptionValue@magnification
    ]
   ]
  ]

printStateFromPoint[pt_, useMatex_: True] := If[TrueQ@useMatex,
  Panel@qubitPrettyPrint[
    With[{θ = ArcCos[pt[[3]]], ϕ = 
       ArcTan[If[pt[[1]] == 0, 0, pt[[2]]/pt[[1]]]]},
     Sequence @@ {Cos[θ/2], Exp[I ϕ] Sin[θ/2]}
     ],
    prefix -> "\\left| \\psi \\right\\rangle = ",
    magnification -> 1.6
    ],
  Panel@With[
    {θ = ArcCos[pt[[3]]], ϕ = 
      ArcTan[If[pt[[1]] == 0, 0, pt[[2]]/pt[[1]]]]},
    Style[
     "\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"ψ\"},\n\"Ket\"]\) = " ~~ 
      ToString@Cos[θ/2] ~~ 
      "\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"0\"},\n\"Ket\"]\) + (" ~~ 
      ToString[Exp[I ϕ] Sin[θ/2]] ~~ 
      ") \!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"1\"},\n\"Ket\"]\)",
     texStyle
     ]
    ]
  ]
```

giving for example

[image]

### Print static Bloch sphere

The following prints the 3D Bloch sphere, with parallel and meridian lines, drawn with `surroundingCircles`, which makes use of `splineCircle`, and the labels, which are printed in LaTeX through MaTeX.

```
pointsAndConnection[points_] := 
 Sequence @@ {Sequence @@ Point /@ #, Line@#} &@points
surroundingCircles = GeometricTransformation[
   splineCircle[{0, 0, 0}, 1],
   {
    {RotationMatrix[0, {1, 0, 0}], {0, 0, 0}},
    {RotationMatrix[Pi/2, {1, 0, 0}], {0, 0, 0}},
    {RotationMatrix[Pi/2, {0, 1, 0}], {0, 0, 0}}
    }
   ];

ClearAll@texKet;
texKet[n_, magnification_: 2, useMatex_: True] := If[TrueQ@useMatex,
  MaTeX["\\left|" ~~ ToString@n ~~ "\\right\\rangle", 
   Magnification -> magnification],
  Text@Style[
    StringTemplate["\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"`1`\"},\n\"Ket\"]\)"][
     ToString@n],
    texStyle
    ]
  ]

blochSphere = Graphics3D[
   {
    White, Opacity@0.3, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1],
    Opacity@1, Thickness@0.004, PointSize@0.02,
    Red, pointsAndConnection@{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}},
    Blue, pointsAndConnection@{{1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}},
    Darker@Green, pointsAndConnection@{{0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}},
    Black, Point[{0, 0, 0}],
    Text[texKet[0], {0, 0, 1.2}],
    Text[texKet[1], {0, 0, -1.2}],
    Text[texKet["+"], {1.2, 0, 0}],
    Text[texKet["-"], {-1.2, 0, 0}],
    Text[texKet["L"], {0, 1.2, 0}],
    Text[texKet["R"], {0, -1.2, 0}],
    Gray, Thin, surroundingCircles
    },
   Boxed -> False,
   PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{-1, 1}, 3],
   ImageSize -> 500,
   RotationAction -> "Clip"
   ];
```

This produces the main output graphics, upon which we will build the dynamic part later:

[image]

### Find intersections with the sphere from mouse clicks

When clicking on the Graphics3D with the mouse we get the information on the clicked position through `MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"]`, which we need to process to derive the corresponding point on the sphere.

To do this, we notice that, denoting with $p_1$ and $p_2$ the points on the boundary box (given by `MousePosition`), the points between them are given by
$p(\lambda) = (1-\lambda) p_1 + \lambda p_2$ for $0 \le \lambda \le 1$.
The points on the sphere will therefore be given by $p(\lambda)$ for $\lambda$ such that $\| p(\lambda) \|^2 = 1$.
This is easily made into the equation:
$$
(p^2 + q^2 -2 p q c) \lambda^2 + 2 \lambda (p q c - p^2) + (p^2 -1) =0,
$$
where $p \equiv \|p_1\|$, $q \equiv \|p_2 \|$, and $c \equiv \frac{p_1 \cdot p_2}{\|p_1 \cdot p_2 \|}$.
We solve this with Mathematica obtaining:

```
In[37]:= Solve[
 (p^2 + q^2 - 2 p q c) λ^2 + 
   2 λ (p q c - p^2) + (p^2 - 1) == 0,
 λ
 ]

Out[37]= {{λ -> (-p^2 + c p q - Sqrt[
    p^2 - 2 c p q + q^2 - p^2 q^2 + c^2 p^2 q^2])/(-p^2 + 2 c p q - 
    q^2)}, {λ -> (-p^2 + c p q + Sqrt[
    p^2 - 2 c p q + q^2 - p^2 q^2 + c^2 p^2 q^2])/(-p^2 + 2 c p q - 
    q^2)}}
```

and we can now take this solution and plug it into our function to get the intersections with the sphere given the intercept points with the box:

```
ClearAll@intersectionsWithSphere
intersectionsWithSphere[pt1_, pt2_] := With[{
   p = Norm[pt1], q = Norm[pt2], c = Cos@VectorAngle[pt1, pt2]
   },
  {(-p^2 + c p q - Sqrt[
    p^2 - 2 c p q + q^2 - p^2 q^2 + c^2 p^2 q^2])/(-p^2 + 2 c p q - 
    q^2), (-p^2 + c p q + Sqrt[
    p^2 - 2 c p q + q^2 - p^2 q^2 + c^2 p^2 q^2])/(-p^2 + 2 c p q - 
    q^2)}
  ]
intersectionsWithSphere[{pt1_, pt2_}] := 
 intersectionsWithSphere[pt1, pt2]
```

### Draw angles

As a nice additional touch, we also want to draw the circular arcs representing the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ of the currently selected point on the sphere.
We do this using the functions `drawThetaAngle` and `drawPhiAngle`:

```
drawThetaAngle[pt_] := With[{
   θ = VectorAngle[{0, 0, 1}, pt],
   θ2 = VectorAngle[{pt[[1]], pt[[2]], 0}, pt],
   ϕ = VectorAngle[{1, 0, 0}, {pt[[1]], pt[[2]], 0}]
   },
  Function[plot,
    GeometricTransformation[
     plot,
     RotationMatrix[#, {0, 0, 1}] &@If[pt[[2]] > 0, ϕ, -ϕ].
        RotationMatrix[Pi/2, {1, 0, 0}].
        RotationMatrix[#, {0, 0, 1}] &@
      If[pt[[3]] < 0, -θ2, θ2, 0]
     ]
    ] /@ {
    splineCircle[{0, 0, 0}, .2, {0, θ}],
    RevolutionPlot3D[0, {t, 0, .2}, {theta, 0, θ}, 
      Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow]][[1]]
    }
  ]
drawPhiAngle[pt_] := With[{
   ϕ = VectorAngle[{1, 0, 0}, {pt[[1]], pt[[2]], 0}]
   },
  {
     splineCircle[{0, 0, 0}, .2, {0, #}],
     RevolutionPlot3D[0, {t, 0, .2}, {θ, 0, #}, Mesh -> None, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Cyan]][[1]]
     } &@If[pt[[2]] > 0, ϕ, 2 Pi - ϕ]
  ]
```

### Finally, put everything together:

All that is left is to put the above pieces together, and add the `Point` representing where the user has clicked.
To handle the case where we click outside the sphere we put a single conditional, which verifies that the derived point on the sphere has unit norm (and thus is really on the sphere).

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 1/Sqrt[2] // N, 1/Sqrt[2] // N}},
 Row[{
   EventHandler[
    Show[
     blochSphere,
     Graphics3D[Dynamic@{
        Opacity@1, PointSize@0.02, Point@pt,
        Dashed, Thin, Purple, 
        Line@{{0, 0, 0}, pt, {pt[[1]], pt[[2]], 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
        Dashing[{}], Thickness@0.004, Red, drawThetaAngle[pt],
        Dashing[{}], Thickness@0.004, Blue, 
        Sequence @@ drawPhiAngle[pt]
        }](*,
     RotationAction\[Rule]"Clip"*)
     ],
    {
     "MouseClicked" :> (
       Module[{p1, p2},
        {p1, p2} = MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"];
        With[{newPt = (1 - λ) p1 + λ p2 /. λ -> intersectionsWithSphere[p1, p2][[2]]},
         If[Norm[newPt] == 1, pt = newPt]
         ]
        ]
       )
     },
    PassEventsDown -> True
    ],
   Dynamic@printStateFromPoint[pt]
   }]
 ]
```

This finally produces the dynamic plot shown at the beginning of the plot.

## Full code (except for `splineCircle` and `MaTeX`):

```
ClearAll@qubitPrettyPrint;
Options[qubitPrettyPrint] = {normalized -> False, magnification -> 2, 
   prefix -> ""};
qubitPrettyPrint[c1_, c2_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 If[! TrueQ@OptionValue@normalized,
  MaTeX[
   StringTemplate[
     "`3`\\left(`1`\\right)\\left|0\\right\\rangle + \
\\left(`2`\\right)\\left|1\\right\\rangle"][
    ToString@TeXForm[c1], ToString@TeXForm[c2], 
    ToString@OptionValue@prefix
    ],
   Magnification -> OptionValue@magnification
   ],
  With[{nCoefficients = Normalize[{c1, c2}]},
   MaTeX[
    StringTemplate[
      "`3`\\left(`1`\\right)\\left|0\\right\\rangle + \
\\left(`2`\\right)\\left|1\\right\\rangle"][
     Sequence @@ (ToString@*TeXForm /@ nCoefficients), 
     ToString@OptionValue@prefix
     ],
    Magnification -> OptionValue@magnification
    ]
   ]
  ]
printStateFromPoint[pt_, useMatex_: True] := If[TrueQ@useMatex,
  Panel@qubitPrettyPrint[
    With[{θ = ArcCos[pt[[3]]], ϕ = 
       ArcTan[If[pt[[1]] == 0, 0, pt[[2]]/pt[[1]]]]},
     Sequence @@ {Cos[θ/2], Exp[I ϕ] Sin[θ/2]}
     ],
    prefix -> "\\left| \\psi \\right\\rangle = ",
    magnification -> 1.6
    ],
  Panel@With[
    {θ = ArcCos[pt[[3]]], ϕ = 
      ArcTan[If[pt[[1]] == 0, 0, pt[[2]]/pt[[1]]]]},
    Style[
     "\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"ψ\"},\n\"Ket\"]\) = " ~~ 
      ToString@Cos[θ/2] ~~ 
      "\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"0\"},\n\"Ket\"]\) + (" ~~ 
      ToString[Exp[I ϕ] Sin[θ/2]] ~~ 
      ") \!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"1\"},\n\"Ket\"]\)",
     texStyle
     ]
    ]
  ]
pointsAndConnection[points_] := 
 Sequence @@ {Sequence @@ Point /@ #, Line@#} &@points
surroundingCircles = GeometricTransformation[
   splineCircle[{0, 0, 0}, 1],
   {
    {RotationMatrix[0, {1, 0, 0}], {0, 0, 0}},
    {RotationMatrix[Pi/2, {1, 0, 0}], {0, 0, 0}},
    {RotationMatrix[Pi/2, {0, 1, 0}], {0, 0, 0}}
    }
   ];

ClearAll@texKet;
texKet[n_, magnification_: 2, useMatex_: True] := If[TrueQ@useMatex,
  MaTeX["\\left|" ~~ ToString@n ~~ "\\right\\rangle", 
   Magnification -> magnification],
  Text@Style[
    StringTemplate["\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"`1`\"},\n\"Ket\"]\)"][
     ToString@n],
    texStyle
    ]
  ]

blochSphere = Graphics3D[
   {
    White, Opacity@0.3, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1],
    Opacity@1, Thickness@0.004, PointSize@0.02,
    Red, pointsAndConnection@{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}},
    Blue, pointsAndConnection@{{1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}},
    Darker@Green, pointsAndConnection@{{0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}},
    Black, Point[{0, 0, 0}],
    Text[texKet[0], {0, 0, 1.2}],
    Text[texKet[1], {0, 0, -1.2}],
    Text[texKet["+"], {1.2, 0, 0}],
    Text[texKet["-"], {-1.2, 0, 0}],
    Text[texKet["L"], {0, 1.2, 0}],
    Text[texKet["R"], {0, -1.2, 0}],
    Gray, Thin, surroundingCircles
    },
   Boxed -> False,
   PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{-1, 1}, 3],
   ImageSize -> 500,
   RotationAction -> "Clip"
   ];

ClearAll@intersectionsWithSphere
intersectionsWithSphere[pt1_, pt2_] := With[{
   p = Norm[pt1], q = Norm[pt2], c = Cos@VectorAngle[pt1, pt2]
   },
  {(-p^2 + c p q - Sqrt[
    p^2 - 2 c p q + q^2 - p^2 q^2 + c^2 p^2 q^2])/(-p^2 + 2 c p q - 
    q^2), (-p^2 + c p q + Sqrt[
    p^2 - 2 c p q + q^2 - p^2 q^2 + c^2 p^2 q^2])/(-p^2 + 2 c p q - 
    q^2)}
  ]
intersectionsWithSphere[{pt1_, pt2_}] := 
 intersectionsWithSphere[pt1, pt2]

drawThetaAngle[pt_] := With[{
   θ = VectorAngle[{0, 0, 1}, pt],
   θ2 = VectorAngle[{pt[[1]], pt[[2]], 0}, pt],
   ϕ = VectorAngle[{1, 0, 0}, {pt[[1]], pt[[2]], 0}]
   },
  Function[plot,
    GeometricTransformation[
     plot,
     RotationMatrix[#, {0, 0, 1}] &@If[pt[[2]] > 0, ϕ, -ϕ].
        RotationMatrix[Pi/2, {1, 0, 0}].
        RotationMatrix[#, {0, 0, 1}] &@
      If[pt[[3]] < 0, -θ2, θ2, 0]
     ]
    ] /@ {
    splineCircle[{0, 0, 0}, .2, {0, θ}],
    RevolutionPlot3D[0, {t, 0, .2}, {theta, 0, θ}, 
      Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow]][[1]]
    }
  ]
drawPhiAngle[pt_] := With[{
   ϕ = VectorAngle[{1, 0, 0}, {pt[[1]], pt[[2]], 0}]
   },
  {
     splineCircle[{0, 0, 0}, .2, {0, #}],
     RevolutionPlot3D[0, {t, 0, .2}, {θ, 0, #}, Mesh -> None, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Cyan]][[1]]
     } &@If[pt[[2]] > 0, ϕ, 2 Pi - ϕ]
  ]

DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 1/Sqrt[2] // N, 1/Sqrt[2] // N}},
 Row[{
   EventHandler[
    Show[
     blochSphere,
     Graphics3D[Dynamic@{
        Opacity@1, PointSize@0.02, Point@pt,
        Dashed, Thin, Purple, 
        Line@{{0, 0, 0}, pt, {pt[[1]], pt[[2]], 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
        Dashing[{}], Thickness@0.004, Red, drawThetaAngle[pt],
        Dashing[{}], Thickness@0.004, Blue, 
        Sequence @@ drawPhiAngle[pt]
        }](*,
     RotationAction\[Rule]"Clip"*)
     ],
    {
     "MouseClicked" :> (
       Module[{p1, p2},
        {p1, p2} = MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"];
        With[{newPt = (1 - λ) p1 + λ p2 /. λ -> intersectionsWithSphere[p1, p2][[2]]},
         If[Norm[newPt] == 1, pt = newPt]
         ]
        ]
       )
     },
    PassEventsDown -> True
    ],
   Dynamic@printStateFromPoint[pt]
   }]
 ]
```