# Best way to draw personalized bloch sphere on mathematica

Tags: graphics3d, drawing

I would like, for presentation purpose, to be able to draw sphere with vectors inside (basically I need to work with Bloch spheres). For example this kind of results :

[image]

I need to be able to add vectors on my sphere (like the $|\psi\rangle$), to draw the angle of the vectors respecting to the basis axis (like the $\theta$ and $\phi$ here), etc.

I would like to know a good guide explaining how all this kind of personalised drawings can be done in mathematica.

I have seen some random functions (plotting a sphere, a plane etc) but I am a little lost and I think a guide with examples would be very helpfull.

So what I am asking here is :

- Which kind of functions are the "best" to use for my purpose
- Do you have a good tutorial to help me to understand how to use all these functions together.

Comment: Have you already checked out this question? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125985/how-to-draw-an-interactive-mouse-clickable-3d-bloch-sphere  It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it could be a good start.