# Positive sense of rotations in Cartesian axes

Tags: plotting

Writing:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.05]]
```

I get:

[image]

where the arrows indicate the positive direction of the horizontal and vertical translations.

Now I would also like to highlight the positive sense of the rotations in this plan as follows:

[image]

where the curved arrow would like it to look like the other two (this I traced quickly with Paint).

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: There are plenty of examples with curved arrows in e.g. `Arrow` docs, where are you stuck exactly.

Comment: You can use `arc[]` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10994) in `Arrow[]` to get a circular arc with an arrowhead.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your question, instead of as an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved it. For example, like this:

```
Show[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.05]], 
     Graphics[{Arrowheads[.05], 
               Arrow[BezierCurve[{{.05, -.05}, {.05, .05}, {-.05, .05}}]]}], 
     PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now, writing:

```
Show[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.05], LabelStyle -> White], 
     Graphics[{Arrowheads[.05], 
               Arrow[BezierCurve[{{.05, -.05}, {.05, .05}, {-.05, .05}}]]}], 
     PlotRange -> All]
```

I get:

[image]

which is already a good result. The top would get to this other result:

[image]

but for now I have not found a way.

Comment: What are "cleats" here?

Comment: Try `Ticks -> None`.

Comment: @TeM Please accept your own answer if the problem is solved