# Affine transformation of circular arc in 3D

Tags: graphics3d, geometric-transform

Start with a quarter-circle of radius 1 centered at the origin and lying in the $xz$-plane:

```
 arc = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, π/2}]
```

I want to dilate this by a factor of 2 and shift the center to `{3, 0, 0}`, then show the result graphically.

The following does *not* work:

```
shiftAndDilate3D = AffineTransform[{2 IdentityMatrix[3], {3, 0, 0}}]

Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[arc3D, shiftAndDilate3D]]
```

The error I get is that `Graphics3DBox is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At least for this case, it is much better to just apply the affine transformation to the parametric equations directly: `ParametricPlot3D[AffineTransform[{2 IdentityMatrix[3], {3, 0, 0}}] @ {Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]} // Evaluate, {t, 0, π/2}]`.

Comment: @J.M.: That's a refreshingly different approach! I have to look at in the entire context of the more complicated thing I'm actually trying to do. It's worth making an answer!

Comment: I think I kind of understand your confusion now, in light of this and your other question. One problem is that the docs do not give a complete and unambiguous list of primitives that one can point to and say: "these are primitives, and they are the only ones supported by `GeometricTransformation[]`"; [this list](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphicsObjects.html) mixes up directives and primitives, so that doesn't count.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10957/an-efficient-circular-arc-primitive-for-graphics3d

Answer (score 5):

You cannot apply those geometric transformations to the results of the plotting; instead, you should apply them to a [`Graphics` primitive](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphicsObjects.html), e.g. the `Line` object generated by `ParametricPlot`, which you can extract using e.g. `Cases`:

```
arcLine = 
 First@Cases[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, π/2}], _Line, All]

Graphics3D[{
  Red, arcLine,
  Blue, GeometricTransformation[arcLine, shiftAndDilate3D]
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In red in the plot above is your original curve, in blue the transformed one.

Comment: Where in the documentation does it explain what is, and what is not, a "geometric object"?

Comment: @murray I was being loose with words there. I really meant a "`Graphics` primitive", such as those discussed in this guide: [`Graphics` objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphicsObjects.html). I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Alas, the doc page guide/GraphicsObjects does not fully identify or clarify what is, and what is not, a "graphics object". For example, given the answer by Carl Woll to my question, a `ParametricRegion` seems to qualify as such an object, yet is not listed on that guide page. So the documentation list of graphics objects doesn't specify what they are, and certainly -- and this is perhaps a real design defect -- the `Head` of these objects doesn't tell you that they are "graphics objects"!

Answer (score 5):

You could work with regions instead. Your arc:

```
arc = ParametricRegion[{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, {{t, 0, \[Pi]/2}}];
```

The transformed arc:

```
shiftAndDilate3D = AffineTransform[{2 IdentityMatrix[3], {3, 0, 0}}];
new = TransformedRegion[arc, shiftAndDilate3D];
```

Visualization:

```
Show[
    Region[arc, BaseStyle->Red],
    Region[new, BaseStyle->Blue],
    Axes->True
]
```

[image]

Comment: How should one know from the Mathematica documentation that `ParametricRegion` is a "region" suitable for the 1st argument to `TransformedRegion`? (The documentation involving `GeometricTransformatino`, `Region`, etc., is sadly deficient. As with `Image`, these things seem to have been thrown into Mathematica without sufficient exposition, or perhaps even without sufficient coherence for the various kinds of things, on the one hand, and sufficient distinctions among them, on the other hand.)

Comment: On the one hand, I like this answer better than the others because it is more direct. On the other hand, it uses yet a different type of object, namely, a "region".

Comment: But I'm annoyed by the different method to style the resulting graphics display, namely, through use of the `BaseStyle` option of `Region` instead of the usual `PlotStyle` option of `ParametricPlot3D` and so many other graphics and graphics 3D functions. Moreover, why should it be necessary to wrap the result of a `ParametricRegion` expression with a `Region`? Either there's something fundamental here I don't understand, or else a whole slew of graphics-like or geometric-like constructs have been thrown into recent versions of Mathematica without sufficient rationalization of the whole domain.

Comment: Further rant: Why does `ParametricRegion` take as 2nd argument a list of lists (of parameters and their extent), whereas `ParametricPlot3D` uses the parameter information as a list, then another list, etc.?

Comment: @murray Lots of questions. For a brief overview of regions, see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricComputation. Basically, a region is a computable object. Region is a function that displays the object (similar to RegionPlot). Show converts a region object to a Graphics/Graphics3D object. ParametricRegion has a different syntax because it supports arguments without bounds, e.g., `ParametricRegion[{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, t]`.

Comment: Is `ParametricRegion[{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, t]` a region and, if not what is it? In what sense is it that "`Show` converts a region object to a `Graphics`/Graphics3D`" object? If I evaluate `Show[ParametricRegion[{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, t]]` I get error that "ParametricRegion is not a type of graphics`. If I evaluate `Region[ParametricRegion[{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, t]]` I get a graphical display, without any additional use of `Show`, and I see no way to discover an object here whose head is `Graphics3D`.

Comment: In fact, after one evaluates `Region[ParametricRegion[{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, t]]`, the result of `Head[%]` is `Region` and not `Graphics3D` !

Comment: @murray As in my answer, `Show @ Region @ ParametricRegion[{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, t]` will produce a Graphics3D object.

Comment: Another dissonance between such geometric regions and graphics: `Region` works equally well in dimensions 2 and 3 (and 1), whereas we have the dichotomy between `Graphics` and `Graphics3D`. Which suggests either that the original "graphics" design idea of "graphics objects" was wrongly imagined or that the way "regions" fit into that original design is not yet well articulated.

Answer (score 4):

Use `arc3D[[1]]` (which contains all the graphics primitives and their styles) as the first argument of `GeometricTransformation`:

```
arc3D = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, π/2}]
Show[arc3D, 
 Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[arc3D[[1]], shiftAndDilate3D] /. l_Line :> {Orange, l}],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Rather, I get an error message: "An improperly formatted option was encountered while reading a Graphics3DBox. The left-hand side of the option was not a symbol or string."

Comment: @murray, forgot a comma before `PlotRange` (fixed now).

Comment: Sorry, I should have caught that!