# Rotate a circle in 3D space with RotationTransform

Tags: graphics3d, geometric-transform

This is related to my confusion over how to combine graphics objects and geometric objects: see [Affine transformation of circular arc in 3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192809/affine-transformation-of-circular-arc-in-3d#192809).

Why does evaluating the `Show` expression below cause the error

> Graphics3DBox is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive

```
shift = AffineTransform[{IdentityMatrix[3], {2, 0, 0}}];
circ = 
  ParametricPlot3D[shift[{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}], {t, 0, 2 π}, 
    PlotStyle -> Green];
rot[angle_] := RotationTransform[angle, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}];

Show[
  Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[circ, rot[π/2]]],
     Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
     AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, PlotRange -> 3]
```

Comment: use `circ[[1]]` in `GeometricTransformation`?

Answer (score 4):

The output of [`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D) is a [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D) object, and [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation) must receive primitives instead. So use:

```
Show[Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[circ[[1]], rot[Pi/2]]],
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, PlotRange -> 3]
```

[image]

A region approach would be:

```
circ = ParametricRegion[shift[{Cos[t],0,Sin[t]}],t];
Show[
    Region[TransformedRegion[circ, rot[Pi/2]], BaseStyle->{Thick, Green}],
    Boxed->False, Axes->True, AxesOrigin->{0,0,0}, PlotRange->3
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your indulgence. I'm still bothered by the relationship between "Graphics3D objects" and "[geometric] primitives". Eventually the distinction may penetrate my obviously thick skull.  (I don't think I've ever had this much trouble mapping Mathematica's language design into my mental maps.)