# project adding a cylinder

Tags: graphics3d, finite-element-method

Hey guys I am having trouble adding a cylinder to the bottom of this shape. Shapeways won't 3D design this because the bottom is "too sharp and edged" so they asked me to add a curvy cylinder shape to the bottom of this hat like shape. Any suggestions?

```
product1 = RegionPlot3D[
    (x^3 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1) && ((x - 1.5)^3 + y + .5^3 + z^1/2 <= 1),
    {x, -1, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotPoints -> {300, 300, 300}, MeshStyle -> None, 
    BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Gray, Axes -> True, 
    Boxed -> True]
```

edit: I researched BSplineCurve. Would that method work here? I ended up making a closed curve but having trouble positioning the 3D tube at the bottom of my original shape. Any ideas? Heres the code.

```
Graphics3D[
   Tube[BSplineCurve[{{-1, 2, .5}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, .5}, {-1, -1, -1}}, 
   SplineClosed -> True]], Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

Comment: question after the edit: why not use the cylinder since you want a cylinder? RegionPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 < x), {x, -1, 2}, {y, -2, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> {50, 50, 50}, MeshStyle -> None, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Gray, Axes -> True, 
 Boxed -> True]

Comment: I tried making a cylinder but lining it up exactly at the bottom of the original shape was too difficult so I decided to just make the points myself and make a tube like object. Any ideas how to get the cylinder aligned perfectly?  EDIT: It was difficult for me to align the cylinder flat side first and attach it to the bottom of the original shape. That's where I am struggling.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I see the point. If something comes in mind I will let you know

Answer (score 5):

## Bell with fillet

I will call the main shape a bell since it reminds me of one. Fillets are a CAD concept to round off sharp edges. We will attempt to create a fillet within Mathematica.  To print a 3D object successfully, there are often requirements that the mesh is defect-free. Often the graphics look good, but the mesh may not be watertight or may have other errors. The following analysis and workflow will be used to create a defect-free mesh that should be suitable for 3D printing.

### Analysis

The final shape is an implicit region that appears to be the intersection between the bell shape and another shape. If we look at the shape separately, it appears that the bell shape is completely contained within the other shape, and therefore the other shape is superfluous as shown below:

```
(*Bell-shaped equation*)
eq1 = (x^3 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1);
(*Other shape equation*)
eq2 = ((x - 3/2)^3 + y + (1/2)^3 + z^1/2 <= 1);
Clear[bell]
bell = ImplicitRegion[eq1 && (-1 <= x <= 1), {x, y, z}];
ir2 = ImplicitRegion[eq2, {{x, -1, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -3/2, 3/2}}];
regbell = Region[Style[bell, Directive[Opacity[0.8], Green]]];
reg2 = Region[Style[ir2, Directive[Opacity[0.5], Cyan]]];
sz = 600;
Show[{regbell, reg2}, ViewProjection -> "Perspective", 
 ViewPoint -> {Bottom, Left, Front}, ImageSize -> sz, 
 Background -> RGBColor[0.84`, 0.92`, 1.`], Boxed -> False]
Region[bell, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Initial shapes]

The bell shape appears to be a volume of revolution about the x-axis.

```
(*Solve for Y as a function of X*)
sol = Solve[(eq1 /. LessEqual -> Equal /. z -> 0) && -1 <= x <= 1 && 
   y >= 0, y]
yFn = x |-> sol[[1, 1, 2, 1]] // Evaluate
plt = Plot[yFn[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Curve of revolution]

#### Creating a fillet

In SolidWorks, we can create an equation based curve and extended tangent line at the endpoint where we want to add the fillet as shown below:

[image: Curve with extended tangent line]

The fillet is basically a circle tangent to the curve to avoid any kinks and blunt an edge's sharpness. The following image shows the fillet in the context of the whole curve of revolution, as shown below:

[image: Fill it in context of the whole curve of revolution]

The next image shows the tangent circle with various geometric relations that we may use later.

$$\left( {{x_0},{y_0}} \right) = \left( {{x_0},\sqrt {1 - {x_0}^3} } \right)$$

$$center = \left( {{x_0} - rsin\theta ,{y_0} - r\cos \theta } \right)$$

[image: Zoom of the filleted region]

```
Clear[theta]
theta[x_Symbol] := ArcTan[D[-yFn[x], x]]
theta[x : (_Integer | _Real)] := ArcTan[D[-yFn[y], y] /. y -> x]
Clear[center]
center[x_, r_] := {x - r Sin[theta[x]], yFn[x] - r Cos[theta[x]]}
```

We can grab the implicit region of a torus from [`SolidData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolidData.html). We see that the torus is a volume of revolution about the z-axis.

```
SolidData["SolidTorus", "ImplicitRegion"]
Region[SolidData["SolidTorus", "ImplicitRegion"][0.3, 1], 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Torus along z-axis]

Therefore, we will need to rotate the torus to revolve around the x-axis and translate it along the x-axis. We can accomplish the following transformation.

```
RotationTransform[π/2, {0, 1, 0}]@*
  TranslationTransform[{-xc, 0, 0}]@{x, y, z}
Clear[xtorus]
xtorus[x0_, r_] := Module[{c, xc, yc},
  {xc, yc} = center[x0, r];
  c = yc;
  ImplicitRegion[(c - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2 + z^2 <= r^2 /. 
    Thread[{x, y, z} -> {z, y, -x + xc}], {x, y, z}]
  ]
xtorus[x0, a]
Region@xtorus[-1, 1/10]
```

[image: X oriented torus]

Now, we will combine the torus with the disk to create a rounded plate as shown below:

```
Clear[disk]
disk[x0_, r_] := Module[{c0, c, xmin, xmax},
  c0 = center[x0, r];
  {xmin, xmax} = {# - r, # + r} &[c0[[1]]];
  c = c0[[2]];
  ImplicitRegion[y^2 + z^2 <= c^2 && xmin <= x <= xmax, {x, y, z}]
  ]
Print["Flat disk"]
Region@disk[-1, 1/10]
Clear[roundedPlate]
roundedPlate[x0_, a_] := RegionUnion[disk[x0, a], xtorus[x0, a]]
Print["Rounded plate"]
Region@roundedPlate[-1, 1/10]
```

[image: Rounded plate]

### Creating the final mesh

First, we need to import the FEM package.

```
(* Import required FEM package *)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
```

We can show that the initial bell-shaped object separates into 2 feature surfaces delineated by the sharp edge.

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[bell, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> .05}, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1];
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> "BoundaryGrouping"]]
```

[image: Sharp edged bell]

We can Union the bell-shaped object with the rounded plate object. The final object shows a single feature free of mesh defects using [`FindMeshDefects`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMeshDefects.html) and, therefore, should be suitable for 3D printing.

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[RegionUnion[bell, roundedPlate[-1, 1/10]], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> .05}, "MeshOrder" -> 1];
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> "BoundaryGrouping"]]
FindMeshDefects[MeshRegion[bmesh]]
```

[image: Defect free blunt bell]

Answer (score 3):

Set `MeshFunctions` to $x$ and set $x=-1$,`MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, Mesh -> {{-1}}`

```
product1 = 
 RegionPlot3D[(x^3 + y^2 + z^2 <= 
     1) && ((x - 1.5)^3 + y + .5^3 + z^1/2 <= 1), {x, -1, 3}, {y, -2, 
   2}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, Mesh -> {{-1}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Thickness[.02], Red}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Gray, Axes -> True, Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

Or if you want a cylinder,we can construct it first by setting $x=-1$ to get the section and then extend $x$ from $-1$ to $-2$ to get the cylinder.

```
product1 = 
  RegionPlot3D[(x^3 + y^2 + z^2 <= 
      1) && ((x - 1.5)^3 + y + .5^3 + z^1/2 <= 1) , {x, -1, 
    3}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   MaxRecursion -> 4, Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> Gray, Axes -> True, Boxed -> True];
cylinder = 
  RegionPlot3D[((x^3 + y^2 + z^2 <= 
         1 && (x - 1.5)^3 + y + .5^3 + z^1/2 <= 1) /. x -> -1) // 
    Evaluate, {x, -2, -1}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   Mesh -> None];
Show[product1, cylinder, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 3}, Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the excellent `splineCircle` function from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10958/862) to create your `BSplineCurve`.

Use [`GeometricTransformation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation.html) to rotate and translate the tube into position.

```
Show[product1, 
 Graphics3D[{Red, 
   GeometricTransformation[
    Tube[splineCircle[{0, 0, 0}, Sqrt[2]], 0.05], 
    TranslationTransform[{-1, 0, 0}] . 
     RotationTransform[π/2, {0, 1, 0}]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: That is brilliant! Works perfectly! Thank you very much :)