# RegionPlot3D problem with PlotStyle

Tags: style, plot-themes, plotting

Been having a problem with RegionPlot3D.
Let's say I want to plot a cube like this

```
RegionPlot3D[(Abs[x] <= 10) && (Abs[y] <= 10) && (Abs[z] <= 10),
 {x, -11, 11}, {y, -11, 11}, {z, -11, 11}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue], 
Mesh -> False, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: This is ok]
which is super.

But now I change the PlotStyle to a Directive,

```
RegionPlot3D[(Abs[x] <= 10) && (Abs[y] <= 10) && (Abs[z] <= 10)
 , {x, -11, 11}, {y, -11, 11}, {z, -11, 11}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.4]], Mesh -> False, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

and get Pink death:
[image: this is not ok]
The thing is, I can move the mouse over the box and hold the clicker in order to rotate, and the semi clear box shows you. The instant I stop holding the mouse clicker the pink square returns.
I've messed around with adding brackets to the Directive, and checked all combinations of deleting all the other options, and the order they're in, and boiled it down to Directive having an Opacity being the problem.

I've restarted Mathematica multiple times, but nothing changes. Thoughts?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the actual code you use, not an image of the code., so that readers can run the code without retyping it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.  Try restarting Mathematica.

Comment: please post your code also

Comment: Code added. Restarted Mathematica multiple times, no change.

Comment: I have copied your code from the question and still cannot reproduce your second plot.  Have you tried copying this code yourself into a new notebook and running it?

Comment: I think this is the same issue as https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245796/opacity-on-mac-does-not-work, and you could try switching the rendering issue as described there.

Comment: @BrettChampion You're my hero. Thank you.

Comment: I am able to evaluate the second plot in Mma 12.3 on Win 10 Pro.  What Mma version and OS are you using?