# Show distances, angles, and torsions with MoleculePlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, chemistry

I would like to display some bond lengths, bond angles, and torsion angles of a molecule with MoleculePlot3D.

For the example

```
mol = Molecule["hydrogenperoxide"];
```

I would like to obtain something like the following figures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use `Show[MoleculePlot3D[mol], Graphics3D[{Text[<your text>, <coordinates>]}]]`.  You just need to compute the coordinates you want to place the text at.

Comment: @JasonB. Thank you. I have updated my question with the figures that I would like to generate.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? Computing the planes/lines to display or actually displaying them as `Graphics3D` objects?

Comment: @b3m2a1 I can calculate the distances and angles, so they can be assumed to be known.

Comment: Then just add a `InfintePlane` from the normals needed for the dihedral angle `{Dashed, Line[{...}]}` for the bond distance line, and use this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10957/an-efficient-circular-arc-primitive-for-graphics3d?noredirect=1&lq=1 for the arcs for the angles. Then layer on @JasonB.'s comment for the text labels and you're done

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you very much! I am now interested in the dashed "distance" line. I can draw this line between atomic positions P1 and P2, but I am struggling seriously with the label. My preferences about the label are as follows: (a) it should be placed ABOVE the dashed line, (b) it should be located around the CENTER of the dashed line, P1+P2, and (c) it should be PARALLEL to the dashed line even while the output figure is rotated. Is there any chance to have all the three settings?

Comment: @TobiR that's a harder problem but that's really a _label placement_ problem and I'm guessing has been answered somewhere on this site. You'll in effect have `Text["label", Dynamic@getLabelPosition[p1, p2]]` and `getLabelPosition` will refer to the `EvaluationBox` to get settings for the `Graphics3D`

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks. I tried to use `Graphics3D[{Dashed, Line[{p1, p2}], {Text["szarfos", EvaluationBox -> Dynamic@getLabelPosition[p1, p2]]}}, Boxed -> False]`, but this command places the text in a wrong place and orientation, and does not follow the rotation of the figure. Could you please help me what the problem is?

Comment: @b3m2a1 I have posted a separate question about this problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257846/rotate-the-label-when-rotating-the-output-image-with-graphics3d. Could you please provide an answer to that?