# Rotate the label when rotating the output image with graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d, dynamic, labeling, text, labeled

I am interested in drawing a labelled dashed line through points `p1` and `p2` with `Graphics3D`.
The code doing this job is the following:

```
p1 = {0, 0, 0};
p2 = {0, 1, 0};
Graphics3D[{Text[Style["DUMA", 30], (p1 + p2)/2], {Dashed, Line[{p1, p2}]}}, Boxed -> False]
```

This code provides the following output:

[image]

However, when I rotate the output image (highlighted in orange box in the above figure) by 90 degrees clockwise, I receive the following result:

[image]

Could you please help me how to modify my code to rotate the label simultaneously with the output image. The result that I expect is as follows:

[image]

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/257829/58370).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi OK, but what is the answer to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

```
p1 = {0, 0, 0}; p2 = {0, 1, 0};
label = Rotate[Text[Style["DUMA", 100]], π/2];
vtc = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
center = Mean[{p1, p2}]; dir = .1 Normalize[p2 - p1]; normal = {1, 1, 
  1}; conormal = .05 Normalize@Cross[dir, normal]; frame = {conormal, 
  dir}; coords = {{center + {-1, -1} . frame, 
   center + {1, -1} . frame, center + {1, 1} . frame, 
   center + {-1, 1} . frame}}; Graphics3D[{{Dashed, Line[{p1, p2} ], 
   Red, Point[p2]}, {Texture[label], EdgeForm[Cyan], 
   Polygon[coords, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {vtc}]}}, 
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
```

[image]

**Original**

```
p1 = {0, 0, 0};
p2 = {0, 1, 0};
label = Text[Style["DUMA", 100]];
vtc = RotateLeft[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}, 1];
center = Mean[{p1, p2}];
dir = .1 Normalize[p2 - p1];
normal = .1 Normalize@{1, -1, 1};
conormal = Cross[dir, normal];
coords = {{center + {-1, -1} . {dir, normal}, 
    center + {1, -1} . {dir, normal}, center + {1, 1} . {dir, normal},
     center + {-1, 1} . {dir, normal}}};
Graphics3D[{Dashed, 
  Line[{p1, p2}], {Texture[label], EdgeForm[Cyan], 
   Polygon[coords, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {vtc}]}}, 
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
```

[image]

Comment: `p1 = {0, 0, 0};
p2 = {0, 1, 0};
label = Text[Style["DUMA", 100]];
vtc = RotateLeft[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 1];
center = Mean[{p1, p2}];
dir = .1 Normalize[p2 - p1];
normal = .1 Normalize@{1, -1, 1};
conormal = .05 Normalize@Cross[dir, normal];
frame = {conormal, dir};
coords = {{center + {-1, -1} . frame, center + {1, -1} . frame, 
    center + {1, 1} . frame, center + {-1, 1} . frame}};
Graphics3D[{Dashed, 
  Line[{p1, p2}], {Texture[label], EdgeForm[Cyan], 
   Polygon[coords, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {vtc}]}}, 
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]`

Comment: It is nice, thanks. The commands you posted below your answer provide "Duma" rotated in a strange way which is unreadable without changing the orientation of our head. ;) Can you give a solution which rotates the text by 180 degrees counterclockwise in this particular case and in general case, such that one can read the text without rotating her head?

Comment: @TobiR  set `vtc = RotateLeft[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 3];` instead of `vtc = RotateLeft[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 1];`

Comment: @cvgmnt After replacing the row you mentioned, I still can get line oritentations where "AMUD" (with "inverted" D) is shown instead of "DUMA".

Comment: @TobiR  See the updated.

Comment: @cvgmnt Thanks. Still if you rotate the dashed line by 90 degrees counterclockwise, then you get "Duma" upside down.