How can I get this part intersection of plane and a sphere?
I am trying to draw this picture

I tried
Clear["Global`*"];
a = 3;
b = 5;
h = 5;
pA = {0, 0, 0};
pB = {a, 0, 0};
pC = {a, b, 0};
pD = {0, b, 0};
pS = {0, 0, h};
lSB = InfiniteLine[{pS, pB}];
lSC = InfiniteLine[{pS, pC}];
lSD = InfiniteLine[{pS, pD}];
pK = RegionNearest[lSB, pA];
pM = RegionNearest[lSC, pA];
pH = RegionNearest[lSD, pA];
reg = Region[
   Style[RegionIntersection[Circumsphere[{pB, pC, pH, pK}], 
     InfinitePlane[pH, {pH - pM, pH - pK}]], Directive[Thick, Green]]];
\[ScriptCapitalR] = ConvexHullRegion[{pA, pB, pC, pD, pS}];
sphericalOffsetFixed[point_, radius_, theta_, phi_] := 
  Module[{}, 
   point + radius {Sin[phi] Cos[theta], Sin[phi] Sin[theta], 
      Cos[phi]}];
labelPointsSphericalFixed[points_List, labels_List, radii_List, 
   angles_List] := 
  Table[Text[Style[labels[[i]], Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    sphericalOffsetFixed[points[[i]], radii[[i]], angles[[i, 1]], 
     angles[[i, 2]]]], {i, Length[points]}];
radii = {0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3}; 

angles = {{3 Pi/4, 3 Pi/4}, {0, -Pi/2}, {Pi, Pi/6}, {Pi/2, 
    Pi/3}, {Pi/2, Pi/2}, {3 Pi/2, Pi/6}, {Pi/4, Pi/3}, {3 Pi/2, Pi/6}};
labels = 
  labelPointsSphericalFixed[{pA, pB, pC, pD, pS, pH, pK, pM}, {"A", 
    "B", "C", "D", "S", "K", "H", "M"}, radii, angles];
my = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], 
    FaceForm[{Pink, Opacity[0.2]}], \[ScriptCapitalR], labels, Thick, 
    Orange, Line[{{pH, pA}, {pK, pA}, {pM, pA}}], 
    Circumsphere[{pA, pB, pC, pH}]}, Boxed -> False];
Show[{reg, my}]


How to get this part of picture?


Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10957/an-efficient-circular-arc-primitive-for-graphics3d

Don't you mean pyramid and a sphere???

Clear["Global`*"];
a = 3;
b = 5;
h = 5;
pA = {0, 0, 0};
pB = {a, 0, 0};
pC = {a, b, 0};
pD = {0, b, 0};
pS = {0, 0, h};
lSB = InfiniteLine[{pS, pB}];
lSC = InfiniteLine[{pS, pC}];
lSD = InfiniteLine[{pS, pD}];
pK = RegionNearest[lSB, pA];
pM = RegionNearest[lSC, pA];
pH = RegionNearest[lSD, pA];


get the ball from the sphere and use RegionDifference.
Use RegionPlot3D to draw the boundary of the piece of sphere H-M-K-A.

sphere = Circumsphere[{pB, pC, pH, pK}];
ball = Ball @@ sphere;
pyramid = Pyramid[{pA, pB, pC, pD, pS}];
reg1 = RegionDifference[pyramid, ball];
reg2 = RegionDifference[ball, pyramid];
plot = RegionPlot3D[
   DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[pyramid, sphere], 
    MaxCellMeasure -> .001], 
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive@{AbsoluteThickness[3], Cyan}, 
   PlotStyle -> None];
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.2], Lighter@Purple}, EdgeForm[], 
  FaceForm[LightRed], Opacity[.6], Purple, 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg1, MaxCellMeasure -> .001], LightRed, 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg2, MaxCellMeasure -> .001,AccuracyGoal -> 3], plot[[1]]}, 
 Boxed -> False]


