# Rotating 3DPlot into animated gif

Tags: graphics3d, animation

I'm trying to make an animated gif of a 3D plot by rotating the plot in its middle, around a vertical axis.
I used the tricks gave by F'x and Heike in this thread [autorotating 3D plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/autorotating-3d-plots) but I encountered some difficulties to get the right axis (parallel to the Axis3 in code).
My need is to rotate my 3D plot slowly as a spinning top from its center.

```
rotateMeHarder1[g_, vertical_, viewpoint0_, center_List: {0, 0, 0}, nframes_Integer: 15, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=  Module[{grlist},  grlist = Table[ Show[g, ViewVertical -> vertical,  ViewVector -> {RotationMatrix[2 Pi/nframes i,  vertical].(viewpoint0 - center) + center, center}, SphericalRegion -> True, opts], {i, 0, nframes - 1}]]

p = ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> All, AxesLabel -> {"Axis1", "Axis2", "Axis3"}, PlotRange -> Full]
grlist = rotateMeHarder1[p, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, 10, ViewAngle -> 110 Degree]

ListAnimate[grlist]
```

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2565/12

Comment: also related http://stackoverflow.com/a/5603326/353410 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/5377618/353410

Comment: I think that my problem come from the fact that don't understand how work ViewVector, ViewCenter, etc... and that documentation in mathematica is not sufficiently explicit for me: ViewVector -> {{5, -5, 5}, {5, 0, -5}} those 2x3 numbers rely to what? thanks for advices. Where/how can I find the coordinates of the edges of a graphe and its center?

Comment: You might want to look into how the old function `SpinShow[]` in the old package `Graphics\`Animation\`` was implemented...

Comment: More related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/57

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suppose you don't want something like this? (Sorry about the 750KB GIF...)

[image: stupid animated gif]

```
data = Table[Sin[x y], {x , 0, Pi, Pi/20},  {y, 0, Pi, Pi/20}];
animation = Table[ListPlot3D[data,
    DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    SphericalRegion -> True,
    Axes -> False, Boxed -> False,
    ViewVector -> {5 Sin[t], 5 Cos[t], Sin[10 t]}], {t , 0, Pi, 
    Pi/40}];
Export["animated.gif", animation, "DisplayDurations" -> .1]
```

Comment: Are we drunk, or on a ship?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's "Plot like a pirate" day...

Comment: Drink up, me 'earties, yo ho. :-)

Comment: will be perfect if it gave me an infinite rotating style and a sailing on a smoother sea ;-) Really thanks for the helps guys and Yo-ho-ho!