# Animate curve parametric plot on a surface

Tags: plotting, graphics, animation

I have a surface

```
s = Plot3D[{x,y,F[x,y]},{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]
```

with $F$ predefined, and a curve

```
c = ParametricPlot3D[{g1[t],g2[t],F[g1[t],g2[t]]},{t,0,1}]
```

with $g1,g2$ predefined. $c$ is therefore a curve on the surface $s$. If I want to show both the objects together I can use

```
Show[s,c]
```

but how can I animate the trajectory described by the curve $c$ on the surface $s$?

Comment: Check out `Animate` and replace `{t,0,1}` with `{t,0,u}`, and let `u` be the changing variable in `Animate`.

Comment: Read the documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Without functions, let's make up our own.  I'm going to take a guess here that the definition of `s` in the question really requires ParametricPlot3D:

```
F[x_, y_] := Sin[x] Cos[y];
g1[t_] := t;
g2[t_] := Cos[t];
```

Generate the surface:

```
s = ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, Sin[x] Cos[y]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, 
   Pi}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.9]]
```

Create an animate of the contour by animating over the end value of the contour:

```
Animate[  
 Show[s, ParametricPlot3D[{g1[u], g2[u], F[g1[u], g2[u]]}, {u, -Pi, 
    endu}, PlotStyle -> Thick, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]], {endu, -Pi, 
  Pi}]
```

[image]

Use a `Table` instead of `Animate` to create a series of images that can be exported as an animated gif as described in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! Just one last question: how can I export it into a gif?

Comment: If you're new to Mathematica you'll want to have a look around this site for lots of good information.  Creating animated gifs [can be found here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4568/7167) among other places.