# How to combine ListPlot and ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have a plane drawn by `ListPlot3D` and I have one intersection of that 3D image drawn by `ListPlot`. How can I combine these two?

Comment: [Very closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34888/7167)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made some data for a `ListPlot3D` plotting.

```
data = Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}];
eq1 = ListPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6],Mesh -> {20, 4, 20}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
eq2 = ListPlot[data[[2]], Joined -> True]
```

> [image: Blockquote]'

I selected second list of the data for intersected line.

```
listplot = Join[{Thickness[0.01], Red},
    Replace[Cases[eq2, Line[a_], -1], {a_, b_} -> {a, 2, b}, {3}]] // 
   Graphics3D;
Show[eq1, listplot]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

And you can use `Manipulate` for showing the full `ListPlot` lines.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ListPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6], Mesh -> {0, 4, 0}],
  Graphics3D[Join[{Thickness[0.01], Red},
    Replace[Cases[ListPlot[data[[i]], Joined -> True], Line[_], -1], {a_, b_} -> {a, i, b}, {3}]]]
  ], {i, 1, 6, 1}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 6):

You  can also use `Mesh` to show the second list in a single `ListPlot3D` as follows:

```
data = Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}];
(* using the same set-up as in Junho Lee's answer *) 

ListPlot3D[data, PlotStyle->Opacity[0.6], Mesh->{20, {1, {2, Directive[{Thick, Red}]}, 3, 4, 5}}]
```

[image]

Multiple 2D slices:

```
ListPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6], 
 Mesh -> {20, {1, {2, Directive[{Thick, Red}]}, 3, {4, Directive[{Thick, Blue}]}, 5}}]
```

[image]

Multiple 2D slices in different directions:

```
ListPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6],
 Mesh -> {Range[0, 6,  1/4] /. {3 -> {3, Directive[{Thick, Orange , Dashed}]},
                        5 -> {5, Directive[{Thick, Purple , DotDashed}]}}, 
         {1, {2, Directive[{Thick, Red}]}, 3, {4, Directive[{Thick, Blue}]}, 5}}]
```

[image]

```
Dynamic@With[{c = Clock[{1, 6, .1}, 2]},
  ListPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6],
   Mesh -> {Range[0, 6, 1/4], {{c, Directive[{Thick, Red}]}}}]]
```

[image]