# Interacting with 3D Graphics, for export

Tags: graphics3d

Are there any export formats which preserve the ability to interact with 3D Graphics?  (In particular, the ability to rotate.)

EDIT:  I've found this question:
[How to make a 3D plot auto-rotate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39398/how-to-make-a-3d-plot-auto-rotate/39401#39401)
which produces an object with head DynamicModule.  Can I export as an animated gif or QuickTime movie?

Comment: I guess it depends on the software you would use to rotate it after the export.

Comment: Save your notebook as a CDF file and download the free CDF player to view and rotate? http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/

Comment: Take a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4537/rotating-3dplot-into-animated-gif).

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate since the OP specifically asks for an export format that "preserves the ability to interact with 3D Graphics" and then settles for a non-interactive animated gif/movie.  I am not clear on what is being asked here.

Comment: @stopple Why is the CDF format not desirable? All the other suggestions pale in comparison with what you can do with CDF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let's take a 3D element:

```
g = PolyhedronData["Spikey"];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

- `Export` as `GIF`:

  As stated [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4537/rotating-3dplot-into-animated-gif) one can `Export` a `List` of images as a `GIF`:

  ```
  animation = Table[Show[g, Boxed -> False, 
    ViewVector -> {0, 5 Cos@u, 5 Sin@u}], {u, 0, Pi, Pi/20}];
  Export["~/animated.gif", animation, "DisplayDurations" -> .1]
  ```

  giving:

  [image]

---

But since the question is "*Are there any export formats which preserve the ability to interact with 3D Graphics? (In particular, the ability to **rotate**.)*" I propose the following which I find very interesting:

- `Export` as `STL`:

  ```
  Export["~/Spikey.stl", g];
  ```

Then one can use [Sketchfab](http://sketchfab.com) to visualize it and get the ability to easily interact with it (click for the full ~3MB GIF):

[image]

- [Spikey](https://sketchfab.com/models/5b20a172d5a34a5386d5711d09fe9353)
- [Sin[x+y^2]](https://sketchfab.com/models/99cbc34d1aeb4992a0415265248fff5b)

Comment: Nice and interesting. +1

Comment: @RunnyKine Thank you, I felt that the [Sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/) idea was worth being shared :)

Comment: Indeed, thanks for sharing :)

Comment: How can I increase the distance in the animation, such that the whole graphic is shown? Have a similar problem and found this question.

Comment: @HighwayJohn Have you looked at the `"DisplayDurations"` option?

Answer (score 1):

Partly a response,
You can work with `Interactive Manipulation` (just hit F1 and search for it) as well with `Import and Export Animations` (you know F1).

```
m = Manipulate[Plot3D[Sin[x y + a], {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 4}]

Export["manipulate1.avi", %]
```

Works fine on `Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)` internals will translate "avi" to "mov".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you are looking for something like **LiveGraphics3D**, a Java applet for interactive rotation of 3D graphics.  Three different summaries:

- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/about/live.html
- http://wwwvis.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/~kraus/LiveGraphics3D/
- http://reference.wolfram.com/webMathematica/tutorial/AppendixLiveGraphics.html

Comment: Cannot download applet from Mr Kraus' homepage. The Mathworld link does not seem to work with Safari 11.0.1 even if I allow the Java plugin everywhere: no animation is visible. :-(

Comment: @LaryxDecidua I'm sorry to say that LiveGraphics3D appears to be an abandoned product.  The Mathworld example isn't working for me either at this point, but I get a message that it is blocked so I should at least try to figure out how to unblock it.  Nevertheless I don't think this will be of much use any more, even though it was once a nice solution.