# Exporting a .gif from 3D graphics while keeping the ability to manipulate

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, export

I am aware of a related [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57178/interacting-with-3d-graphics-for-export) but I think my questions is slightly different. I have a table of 3D graphics (as an example you could think of a ball or torus and each element of the table is a slight rotation so when exported the gif shows the ball or torus rotating). For each frame in Mathematica I can rotate the picture around and change the viewpoint. Is there a way to export the gif while keeping this ability? So as the ball is rotating in the gif, I would be able to change the viewpoint.

For the example in the linked question it would mean taking the gif associated with `animation` and being able to rotate it as it moves.

I hope it is clear what I mean. I think this may too complicated for Mathematica to do.

Comment: GIF is a 2D format, you should export to other 3D format such obj, stl or forthcoming WebGL.

Comment: A long time ago I remember QuickTime VR which could do panoramas but also Object VR where QuickTime would allow you to rotate an object around, displaying frames from a range of angles. The intention was to show an interactive orbit of photo-realistic graphics (and possibly photos of a real object like product photography and showcasing) without the need to render it. These days graphics cards can do a lot more realtime rendering, so I objectvr is not that widespread.

Comment: Of course, you could always write your own viewer (maybe in the browser?) which consumes your frames from Mathematica. See here for an example https://ggnome.com/samples/object2vr/dragon/ and this is the product https://ggnome.com/object2vr/

Comment: @cvgmt If I could export each frame of the gif in a 3D format is there then a way to put them back together we we could see the movement in 3D (coming from each frame) while also being able to rotate this new "3D gif" object?