# Help recreating a gif

Tags: graphics3d, animation

For my math class I am trying to recreate a mathematical GIF. Here is the GIF I wish to make:

[image: the GIF] 
At this point I think I have a 3D function that would work to lay the hexagons on to.

```
Manipulate[Show[ParametricPlot3D[{t Cos[s], Cos[a - t] Sinc[t], t Sin[s]}, {t, 0, 5}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All], PlotRange -> All], {a, 0 , 2 Pi}]
```

While this might not be the perfect function but I think it will work. The next step is getting the hexagons to lay on the surface as it moves.

What would be the best way to have the hexagon on the surface?
A quick clarification. I want to know how to get the hexagons on to the surface I will turn it in to a real GIF once I get that to work.

Comment: You could define plane hexagons and move the vertices vertically according to your function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotating 3DPlot into animated gif](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4537/rotating-3dplot-into-animated-gif)

Comment: Thank you Yves. I will try to do this.

Comment: Related [27202](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27202/how-to-export-this-animation-as-a-gif-file-for-powerpoint-presentation)

Comment: I do not agree that this is a duplicate of that other post. The question is *What would be the best way to have the hexagon on the surface?* not *How can I animate this function?*

Comment: @Pickett Title is _Help recreating a gif_, and so was the first answer.

Answer (score 16):

an approach using graphics primitives:

```
 rmax = 10;
 na=100;
 p=Select[Flatten[Table[Partition[
     Table[ {Sin[#],Cos[# ]}&@ (n Pi/3) +
       {Sqrt[3](1+2 j +  Boole[EvenQ[i]]),3i}/2+{0,0},
                      {n,2,5}],2,1],
            {i,-rmax,rmax},{j,-rmax,rmax}],2], Max[Norm/@#]<rmax&];
 cf[x_] := Hue[ 2/3 (1-Exp[-5 (Norm[x]-1)/rmax])]
 df[a_,x_]:=  (2 Cos[a-#/2] Sinc[#/4]&@(10 Norm[x]/rmax))
 Export["test.gif",z=Table[
   Graphics3D[{Thick,Rotate[Line[ Append[#,df[4 Pi a/na,#]]&/@# , 
                        VertexColors->cf/@ #],2 Pi a/na,{0,0,1}] }&/@p,
              PlotRange->{{-rmax,rmax},{-rmax,rmax},{-2,2}},Boxed->False],{a,1,na}]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. But now colour your lines according to the (dynamic) height.

Comment: Thank you now that is exactly what I was looking for. Any chance you could explain what that code is doing? Beyond the rotation I do not understand what the codes say.

Comment: `p` is a 2d grid of lines and we simply `Append` a third coordinate according to the function.  To use the same function for the color define `cf` something like `cf[a_,x_]:=Hue[ scale df[a,x] ]` and do `VertexColors->cf[a,#]&/@ # &]`

Comment: note this is inefficiently computing  the displacement separately for each segment end (ie 3 times for each vertex). It shouldn't be too much trouble to fix that if performance is an issue.

Answer (score 11):

Here is my version. I took the function `df` from george2079's answer.

```
nodes = Nest[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[Table[# + 2 Cos[Pi/6] {Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}, {theta, Pi/6, 2 Pi, Pi/3}] & /@ #, 1] &, {{0, 0}}, 8];
edges = Table[# + {Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/3}] & /@ nodes;
edges3D[t_] := MapAt[{First@#, Last@#, df[t, Norm@#]} &, edges, {All, All}]
linePrimitives[t_] := Map[Line[#, VertexColors -> {cf[#[[1, 3]]/2 // N], cf[#[[2, 3]]/2]} // N] &, Map[Partition[#, 2, 1] &, edges3D[t]], {2}];

cf[x_] := Blend[{RGBColor[0, 1, 1], Blue, Green}, Abs@x]

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  linePrimitives[t], PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-2, 2}}, 
  Boxed -> False, Background -> Black
  ], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Animation]

To understand what each line does I recommend executing the following lines:

```
(* The centers of the hexagons. *)
Point@nodes // Graphics
(* The points at the corner of the hexagons. *)
ListLinePlot[edges, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

The third line adds the corresponding z value to each pair of x and y values.

The last line is there to divvy up the coordinates of the edges so that I can recast them in the format `Line[pt1,pt2,VertextColors-> colors depending on z values]`, and to do that (there are two `Map`.)

Answer (score 3):

Replace `Manipulate` to `Table` to generate many picture;

```
gif = Table[
   Show[ParametricPlot3D[{t Cos[s], Cos[a - t] Sinc[t], t Sin[s]}, {t,
   0, 5}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All], PlotRange -> All], {a, 0, 2 Pi, .1}];
 Export["a.gif", gif]
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Fixing the plotrange might give an even better animation. Still +1

Comment: `gif = Table[
   Show[ParametricPlot3D[{t Cos[s], Cos[a - t] Sinc[t], t Sin[s]}, {t,
       0, 5}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All], 
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-3, 3}, {-5, 5}}], {a, 0, 2 Pi, .1}];Export["a.gif", gif]`

Comment: @Pickett,The size of gif file was bigger than 2M,BTW, how to restrict the size of the file that be exported?

Comment: The Last time I had to reduce gif size I used gifsicle http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/

Comment: I tried using gifsicle (through the program ImageOptim, which uses it), however that didn't help much in this case. So I simply reduced the number of frames by two, i.e. changed 0.1 to 0.2 in `Table`.