# Obtaining a 3D animation as a drop in a liquid surface

Tags: graphics, animation, simulation, generative-art

Someone could get a similar solution like this animation?

[image]

I believe the solution is useful for demonstrations in class to other users who teach Math.

[Spreading of a Thin Liquid Drop Under the Influence of Gravity, Rotation and Non-Uniform Surface Tension](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4615-0687-4_5)

Comment: If similar is needed then: [63200](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63200/5478). "I declare that I have no idea how to get started" - very convenient :) You can always try a straightforward approach with `Graphics3D` `Table` `Point` and positions dependent of a parameter. p.s. useful search query [animation + generative-art](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generative-art+animation)

Comment: By your comment, now can I have an idea how to start :). If no one, for now, add a solution, I will trying through these references. Grateful.

Comment: I'm going to try to implement a drop of water. Then yes it would be innovative.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51539).

Comment: watching the comments, I found that I don't know do research on the site. How much information that I have not found.

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho. I find that using the search bar *within* the site doesn't work all that great. When I have a question, I usually just google "mathematica stack exchange ..." where "..." are some key-words for what I'm looking for. You can also try searching within `tag`s within the site by searching, for instance, for "[plotting] animation".

Comment: You're asking for a "solution" but don't say what it is the solution **of**. It's certainly not the linear wave equation in two dimensions, because then you would **not** get sine solutions as stated in the question. Just want to point this out so that people don't mistakenly believe this represents a physical wave in 2D.

Comment: Also, it's very important to give the source whenever you post material that hasn't been generated by code you are posting. You may be violating copyright,

Comment: @Jens I took this picture of a Facebook message.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to J.M.

```
drop = SetAlphaChannel[#, ColorNegate@#] &@
  Binarize@Rasterize@
    ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t] (1 - Sin[t]), -3 + 
       r (5/2 (Sin[t] - 1) + 3)}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}, 
     BoundaryStyle -> None, Axes -> False, Frame -> False]
```

Something to start with:

```
circle = Table[
  Translate[
    Point[{##, 0} & @@@ CirclePoints[r, 10 + 20 r]], 
    {0, 0, Dynamic[f[#, t]] &@r}
  ], 
  {r, .5, 20, .5}
];

f[r_, t_] := UnitBox[(r - t)/(2 Pi) - .5] Sin[r - t]; 
t = -4 Pi; 

Column@{
  Trigger[Dynamic[t], {-4 Pi, 20}] ,
  Graphics3D[
   {AbsolutePointSize@2, circle,
    Dynamic @ If[t < -1.9 Pi, 
      Inset[drop, {0, 0, -(t + 2 Pi)}, Automatic, Scaled[{.03, .05}]], 
      {}
    ]
    },
   ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 700, 
   PlotRange -> {20 {-1, 1}, 20 {-1, 1}, 10 {-1, 1}}, 
   ViewAngle -> Pi/16, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {5, 0, 3}, 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic]}
```

[image]

Comment: beautiful...+1  can almost here the drop :)

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks, but let's be clear, it is not the prettiest one :) Though I don't care, my goal in such cases is to create something interactive rather than a neat gif.

Comment: yes it would not be used in Disney CGI...but terse and perhaps motivates...I am off to sleep :)

Comment: Great job! Now I will study your code. I am beginner and I am thrilled to see that there are several solutions using this software.