# How to animate a cube with images on their faces?

Tags: graphics3d, image-processing, animation, image3d

From this code, how could I animate (speed given by the user) this cube at random so that each face shows me a different image.

**EDIT(The idea is that the cube rotates at random and shows different images on each face, it is understood now :(**

```
 $Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[
 Tuples[{0, 1}, 3],
 MapThread[
 {Texture[
 Graphics[ImportString[ExportString[#1, "PDF"], "PDF"][[1, 1]],       Background -> #3]],
 Polygon[#2, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]} &,
{Characters["ABCDEF"],
 {{1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 5, 6, 2}, {1, 3, 7, 5}, {8, 6, 5, 7}, {8, 7, 
   3, 4}, {8, 4, 2, 6}},
 Table[Hue[i/6], {i, 6}]}
]
   ],
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]$
```

**here some example image to put on the faces**

> [enter link description here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51ZQiVNDYPL._SX425_.jpg)
>   [enter link description here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51S7cvjbrqL._SX425_.jpghttps://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61acUMNLNvL._SX425_.jpg)
>   [enter link description here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xRMocaTKL._SX425_.jpg)
>   [enter link description here](https://conideade.com/8475-large_default/numeros-de-carton-205-cm.jpg)
>   [enter link description here](https://conideade.com/8484-thickbox_default/numeros-de-carton-205-cm.jpg)
>   [enter link description here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/417omSNK8-L.jpg)

Comment: Related: [Creating 3D dice](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110295/creating-3d-dice/110365)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 5:** In newer versions (e.g., version 13.3.1) replace `ImportString[ExportString[#1, "PDF"], "PDF"][[1, 1]]` below with

```
ImportString[ExportString[#, "PDF"], {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}, 
  "TextMode" -> "Outlines"][[1, 1]]
```

**Update 4:** Rotations around `x` axis followed by rotations around `y` axis followed by rotations around `z` axis:

```
faces = Polygon[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0,  1}}] & /@ 
  {{1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 5, 6, 2}, {1, 3, 7, 5}, {8, 6, 5, 7}, {8, 7, 3, 4}, {8, 4, 2, 6}};

images = Import /@ 
 {"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51ZQiVNDYPL._SX425_.jpg",
  "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51S7cvjbrqL._SX425_.jpg", 
  "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61acUMNLNvL._SX425_.jpg", 
  "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xRMocaTKL._SX425_.jpg"};

{one, six} = Texture[Graphics[
      ImportString[ExportString[#1, "PDF"], "PDF"][[1, 1]], 
      Background -> #2]] & @@@ Transpose[{{"1", "6"}, {Red, Yellow}}];
textures2 = Join[Texture /@ images, {one, six}];

Animate[Graphics3D[
  Rotate[GraphicsComplex[Tuples[{0, 1}, 3],Transpose[{textures2, faces}]], t, 
   IdentityMatrix[3][[1 + Quotient[t, 2 Pi]]], {1, 1, 1}/2], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", SphericalRegion -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1/2, 3/2}, {-1/2, 3/2}, {-1/2, 3/2}}, 
  Boxed -> False], {t, Range[0, 6 Pi - Pi/120, Pi/120]}]
```

[image]

**Update 3:** Rotations by a random angle around a randomly selected axis:

```
Animate[Graphics3D[Rotate[GraphicsComplex[Tuples[{0, 1}, 3], 
     Transpose[{textures, faces}]], t, RandomChoice[IdentityMatrix[3]]], 
   Lighting -> "Neutral",  SphericalRegion -> True,  Boxed -> False],
 {t, RandomSample[Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/60]]}]
```

[image]

```
frames2 = Table[Graphics3D[
    Rotate[GraphicsComplex[Tuples[{0, 1}, 3], Transpose[{textures, faces}]], t, 
     RandomChoice[IdentityMatrix[3]]], Lighting -> "Neutral", 
     SphericalRegion -> True,  Boxed -> False],
  {t, RandomSample[Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/60]]}];

Export["cube2.gif", frames2]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** Rotating a cube with images on its faces:

```
faces = Polygon[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}] & /@
  {{1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 5, 6, 2}, {1, 3, 7, 5}, {8, 6, 5, 7}, {8, 7, 3, 4}, {8, 4, 2, 6}};

images = Import /@ 
  {"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51ZQiVNDYPL._SX425_.jpg", 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51S7cvjbrqL._SX425_.jpg", 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61acUMNLNvL._SX425_.jpg", 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xRMocaTKL._SX425_.jpg"};

{one, six} = Texture[Graphics[
      ImportString[ExportString[#1, "PDF"], "PDF"][[1, 1]], 
      Background -> #2]] & @@@ Transpose[{{"1", "6"}, {Red, Yellow}}];
textures2 = Join[Texture /@ images, {one, six}];

Animate[Graphics3D[
  GraphicsComplex[Tuples[{0, 1}, 3], Transpose[{textures2, faces}]], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", 
  ViewVector -> 6 { Cos[t], Sin[t], 3 Sin[t]/6 + 1/12}, 
  SphericalRegion -> True], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/60}]
```

[image]

You can control the speed using the second and third buttons.

See also: [this answer by halirutan to a related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174084/125)

**Update:** Using some of the images from the links in OP:

```
images = Import /@ 
  {"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51ZQiVNDYPL._SX425_.jpg", 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51S7cvjbrqL._SX425_.jpg", 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61acUMNLNvL._SX425_.jpg", 
 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xRMocaTKL._SX425_.jpg"};

{one, six} = Texture[Graphics[
      ImportString[ExportString[#1, "PDF"], "PDF"][[1, 1]], 
      Background -> #2]] & @@@ Transpose[{{"1", "6"}, {Red, Yellow}}];
```

Just wrap your images with `Texture` (and add the missing `1` and `6`):

```
textures2 = Join[Texture /@ images, {one, six}];


frames = Table[Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[Tuples[{0, 1}, 3], 
     Transpose[{RandomSample[textures2, 6], faces}]], Lighting -> "Neutral"], {30}];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
textures = Texture[Graphics[ImportString[ExportString[#1, "PDF"], "PDF"][[1, 1]], 
      Background -> #2]] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{CharacterRange["A", "Z"], Hue[#/26] & /@ Range[26]}];

faces = Polygon[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}] & /@
  {{1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 5, 6, 2}, {1, 3, 7, 5}, {8, 6, 5, 7}, {8, 7, 3, 4}, {8, 4, 2, 6}};

frames = Table[Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[Tuples[{0, 1}, 3], 
    Transpose[{RandomSample[textures, 6], faces}]], Lighting -> "Neutral"], {30}]

ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image]

```
Export["cube.gif", frames]
```

[image]

Comment: @ kglr ,ok , thanks , the idea is correct, but as insert pictures on the cube faces no letters
(for example the images of the links that you leave)

Comment: @ kglr ,,first of all, thanks for your time,    is much better, but it seems that you understood me the other way round, it is the cube that rotates at random with images on their faces

Comment: @ kglr sorry  It is in the title
How to animate a cube with images on their faces? ,(maybe I express myself badly)
From this code, how could I animate (speed given by the user) this cube at random so that each face shows me a different image

Comment: @zeros, please see update 2.

Comment: now works fine, thanks for your time

Comment: @zeros, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: how do I rotate more fluid, not jumps

Comment: @zeros, replace `RandomSample[Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/60]]` with `Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/60]` and `RandomChoice[IdentityMatrix[3]]` with `{0,0,1}` to rotated around the `z` axis (`{0,1,0}` for rotating around `y` axis and `{1,0,0}` for rotating around `x` axis). Alternatively, use the approach in update 2 to rotate along a path.

Comment: sorry , with so much change, now I do not work any, can the full final code please

Comment: @ kglr ,something happens and no update works, I could write (copy) the complete code with tosas its variables in your next answer (it tells me that there are some words undefined)

------------------

Comment: @zeros, posted the complete code in update 4.

Comment: @ kglr , now it works, the pc is locked, there was no way to calculate, I'm wondering if you can add an output to animated gif please, greetings and thank you

Comment: @kglr in Mathematica 13.3, I consistently get `X[[1,1]] is longer than depth of the object`, where x is an element of the list of character/color pairs rendered by `ImportString`. The result is the background with no characters. I'm not sure how to fix this. It's probably some breaking change in PDF importing ? but who knows.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin, thank you for bringing this issue up.  I updated the post with a fix.