# Figure in animated GIF is oscillating as it rotates

Tags: plotting, animation, rotation

I'm trying to draw a figure as shown below and make it rotate around the vertical axis (z-axis) automatically.

[image: Figure to be rotated]

This is how I generate the figure and make it rotate:

```
Δϕ = π 14.0/13.0;
p1 = 
  Show[
    Table[
      RegionPlot3D[
        x^2 + y^2 + (z - j)^2 < 0.5^2 && 
        (x - 0.4 Cos[j Δϕ]) Cos[j Δϕ] + (y - 0.4 Sin[j Δϕ]) Sin[j Δϕ] < 0, 
        {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}, {z, -0.5 + j, 0.5 + j}, 
        PlotStyle -> Blue, Mesh -> None], 
      {j, 0, 5}], 
      PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> Automatic];
p2 = 
  Graphics3D[
    Table[
      Arrow[{{0.4 Cos[j Δϕ], 0.4 Sin[j Δϕ], j}, {Cos[j Δϕ], Sin[j Δϕ], j}}], 
      {j, 0, 5}]];
p = 
  Show[{p1, p2}, 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
    ViewPoint -> {0, -10, 0}, ViewCenter -> {0, 0, 2.5}, 
    ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}];
vc = AbsoluteOptions[p, ViewCenter][[1, 2]];
vp = AbsoluteOptions[p, ViewPoint][[1, 2]];
m = RotationMatrix [5 Degree, {0., 0., 1.}];
newvp = m.(vp - vc);
Export["a.gif", 
  Table[
    Show[p, 
      ViewPoint -> MatrixPower[m, j].(vp - vc) + vc, 
      PlotRange -> All], 
    {j, 0, 360/5 - 1}]];
```

This is how the gif file looks like
[image: The output gif file]

I don't understand why the gif is kind of oscillating in the horizontal direction, and the arrows seem turn around when a cycle is done and the next cycle starts. What I want is to have the rotating axis (here the z-axis) fixed while the figure is rotating. Which part of my code is wrong?

Comment: I believe the image is centered in each frame, but because the arrows protrude at different times, the position of the balls changes.

Comment: You need to use a fixed `PlotRange` instead of `PlotRange -> All`, and maybe add a `SphericalRegion -> True` while you're at it.

Comment: I tried fixed `PlotRange`, but it didn't work. Adding `SphericalRegion -> True` only shows a tiny part of the figure.

Comment: I usually draw a white rectangle on the background that's larger than the animation region, so this remains centred. For the arrows, perhaps try with a tube, the one you are using is 2D so it has problems twice per turn.

Comment: Regarding the flipping arrowheads, you can either use 3D arrows or try to add something along the lines `Arrowheads[Medium, Appearance -> "Projected"]` in your 3D expression.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(2565)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2565/121),
[(3759)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3759/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps the following will work for you. Since I worked it out more by trial-and-error than by expertise, there may be unnecessary code that remains. Mainly what I did was the following:

1. Computed the camera position before doing the export by a better method. Your computation of the camera position was the source of the oscillation.
2. Eliminated many options, some of which caused problems and others which were simply redundant. I also added a few options the improve the look of graphics.

```
Δϕ = π 14.0/13.0;

p1 =
  Table[
    RegionPlot3D[
      x^2 + y^2 + (z - j)^2 < 0.5^2 && 
      (x - 0.4 Cos[j Δϕ]) Cos[j Δϕ] + (y - 0.4 Sin[j Δϕ]) Sin[j Δϕ] < 0, 
      {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}, {z, -0.5 + j, 0.5 + j},
      PlotStyle -> Blue,  Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None],
    {j, 0, 5}];

p2 =
  Graphics3D[{
    Black,
    Table[
      Arrow @ Tube[{{0.4 Cos[j Δϕ], 0.4 Sin[j Δϕ], j}, {Cos[j Δϕ], Sin[j Δϕ], j}}], 
      {j, 0, 5}]}];

vp = 
  Table[
    RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}][{0, -50, 3}], 
    {θ, N[2 π Subdivide[36]]}];

Export[
  FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "RotatingSpheres.gif"}],
  Show[p1, p2,
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-.5, 5.5}},
    Axes -> False,
    Boxed -> False,
    BoxRatios -> Automatic,
    SphericalRegion -> True,
    ViewPoint -> #] & /@ vp];
```

[image: gif]

#### Update

At Yves Klett's behest, I have made the arrows into 3D tube-based arrows.

Comment: you are really fast... love the use of vp to vectorise the command.

Comment: Perhaps the use of 3D arrow primitives would be useful to avoid the arrowheads spinning.

Comment: @YvesKlett. I agree. I didn't work on that part of problem. I think there already answers on the site that describe how to 3D primitives to make better 3D arrows.

Comment: @m_goldberg it would be as simple as replacing `Arrow` by `Arrow@Tube` here: `Arrow@Tube[{{0.4 Cos...` (perhaps adding some `Black` on the way, too).

Comment: @YvesKlett. OK, I did it. I admit I was just being lazy.

Comment: nice! There is also `Arrowheads[Medium, Appearance -> "Projected"]` for 2D arrowheads (I just put this here as a reminder).

Comment: Thank you very much. I think the problem also comes from the fact that I combine p1 and p2 into p. I tried `show[p1,p2,...]` instead of `Show[p, ...]` and get what I wanted.